# Advantages of UserDict class?

Tags: python, oop

What are advantages of using **`UserDict`** class?

I mean, what I really get if instead of

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
...
m = MyClass()
m.a = 5
m.b = 7
```

I will write the following:

```
class MyClass(UserDict):
    def __init__(self):
        UserDict.__init__(self)
        self["a"] = 0
        self["b"] = 0
...
m = MyClass()
m["a"] = 5
m["b"] = 7
```

**Edit**: If I understand right I can add new fields to an object in a runtime in both cases?

```
m.c = "Cool"
```

and

```
m["c"] = "Cool"
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[`UserDict.UserDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html?#UserDict.UserDict) has no substantial added value since Python 2.2, since, as @gs mention, you can now subclass `dict` directly -- it exists only for backwards compatibility with Python 2.1 and earlier, when builtin types could not be subclasses. Still, it was kept in Python 3 (now in its proper place in the `collections` module) since, as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html?#collections.UserDict) now mention,

> The need for this class has been
>   partially supplanted by the ability to
>   subclass directly from dict; however,
>   this class can be easier to work with
>   because the underlying dictionary is
>   accessible as an attribute.

`UserDict.DictMixin`, in Python 2, is quite handy -- as the docs say,

> The module defines a mixin, DictMixin,
>   defining all dictionary methods for
>   classes that already have a minimum
>   mapping interface. This greatly
>   simplifies writing classes that need
>   to be substitutable for dictionaries
>   (such as the shelve module).

You subclass it, define some fundamental methods (at least `__getitem__`, which is sufficient for a read-only mapping without the ability to get keys or iterate; also `keys` if you need those abilities; possibly `__setitem__`, and you have a R/W mapping without the ability of removing items; add `__delitem__` for full capability, and possibly override other methods for reasons of performance), and get a full-fledged implementation of `dict`'s rich API (`update`, `get`, and so on). A great example of the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern.

In Python 3, `DictMixin` is gone; you can get *almost* the same functionality by relying on `collections.MutableMapping` instead (or just `collections.Mapping` for R/O mappings). It's a bit more elegant, though not QUITE as handy (see [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue5402), which was closed with "won't fix"; the short discussion is worth reading).

Comment: since '09 things moved a bit in python 3, and DictMixin is back: http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#UserDict.DictMixin - though MutableMapping is indeed suggest for most uses.

Comment: Is this still valid?  Reading "Fluent Python", the author recommends subclassing UserDict because "major caveat: the code of the built-ins (written in C) does not call special (magic) methods overridden by user-defined classes".  This books covers 3.x but does this warning not apply to 2.7 as well?

Comment: @Stefano: There is not now, and I'm pretty sure there has never been, any DictMixin in Python 3's standard library. The link you gave was at the time a link to the Python 2.7.2 documentation (currently a 404).

Comment: @Kundor you seem to be right, though I am left wondering why would I have posted a py2 doc link at the time. There's https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict in py3, maybe I got confused. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I see the UserDict in the official Python 3 documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict but don't see anything about MutableMapping. Most likely, the answer is outdated.

Answer (score 8):

Subclassing the dict gives you all the features of a dict, like `if x in dict:`. You normally do this if you want to extend the features of the dict, creating an ordered dict for example.

BTW: In more recent Python versions you can subclass `dict` directly, you don't need `UserDict`.

Answer (score 7):

It's tricky to overwrite `dict` correctly, while `UserDict` makes it easy. There was some discussion to remove it from Python3, but I believe it was kept for this reason. Example:

```py
class MyDict(dict):

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    super().__setitem__(key, value * 10)


d = MyDict(a=1, b=2)  # Oups MyDict.__setitem__ not called
d.update(c=3)  # Oups MyDict.__setitem__ not called
d['d'] = 4  # Good!
print(d)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 40}
```

`UserDict` inherit `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, so don't have those drawback:

```py
class MyDict(collections.UserDict):

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    super().__setitem__(key, value * 10)


d = MyDict(a=1, b=2)  # Good: MyDict.__setitem__ correctly called
d.update(c=3)  # Good: MyDict.__setitem__ correctly called
d['d'] = 4  # Good
print(d)  # {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
```

Comment: such code is antipattern

Comment: Why would it be antipattern ? Inheriting from `MutableMapping` / `UserDict` are very standard (those classes were designed for this)

Comment: implicitly changing the value. v*10

Comment: This is just a dummy demo showing why inheriting `UserDict` is simpler than `dict`. Of course in practice, the implementation would contain actual code.

Answer (score 5):

Well, as of 3.6 there are certainly some disadvantages, as I just found out.  Namely, `isinstance(o, dict)` returns False.

```
    from collections import UserDict

    class MyClass(UserDict):
        pass

    data = MyClass(a=1,b=2)

    print("a:", data.get("a"))
    print("is it a dict?:", isinstance(data, dict))
```

#### Not a dict!

```
a: 1
is it a dict?: False
```

Change to `class MyClass(dict):` and `isinstance` returns True.

#### However... with UserDict you can step into its implementation.

(pdb-ing into functions/methods is an easy way to see exactly how they work)

```
#assumes UserDict

di = MyClass()

import pdb

#pdb will have work if your ancestor is UserDict, but not with dict
#since it is c-based
pdb.set_trace()
di["a"]= 1
```

Comment: While UserDict does not inherit from a dictionary, the `data` attribute that stores the dict for UserDict objects is a normal dict and can be tested such as `isinstance(mydict.data, dict)`

Answer (score 0):

One additional reason that these other answers don't address for the reasons to keep UserDict around is for the compatibility with PyPy. For dict, PyPy says [here](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#subclasses-of-built-in-types) that:

`Officially, CPython has no rule at all for when exactly overridden method of subclasses of built-in types get implicitly called or not. As an approximation, these methods are never called by other built-in methods of the same object. For example, an overridden __getitem__() in a subclass of dict will not be called by e.g. the built-in get() method.`

So if you create a subclass of dict, use the get method, and are expecting the **getitem** to be called, it won't be. However, if you implement your subclass using UserDict, this will work as you would expect in both Python and PyPy, because UserDict implements the get method as such:

```py
def get(self, key, default=None):
    if key in self:
        return self[key]
    return default
```

You can see the source code for UserDict here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1117

Also - sure, you could just implement the get method yourself when you subclass dict. But why, when you can just use the methods already implemented in UserDict?