# How to detect dict modification?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have subclassed the `dict` and need to detect all its modifications.

(I know I cannot detect an in-place modification of a stored value. That's OK.)

My code:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    super().__setitem__(key, value)
    self.modified = True

def __delitem__(self, key):
    super().__delitem__(key)
    self.modified = True
```

The problem is it works only for a straightforward assignment or deletion. It does not detect changes made by `pop()`, `popitem()`, `clear()` and `update()`.

Why are `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` bypassed when items are added or deleted? Do I have to redefine all those methods (`pop`, etc.) as well?

Comment: I have found a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148419/subclass-dict-userdict-dict-or-abc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this usage, you should not subclass `dict` class, but instead use the abstract classes form the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module of Python standard library.

You should subclass the `MutableMapping` abstract class and override the following methods: `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__iter__` and `__len__`, 
all that by using an inner dict. The abstract base class ensures that all other methods will use those ones.

```
class MyDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}
        # other initializations ...

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.d[key] = value
        self.modified = true
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tested it. If I subclass from `collections.UserDict` which itself inherits from `MutableMapping`, then my original code works as expected without further modifications. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

`pop, popitem, clear, update` are not implemented through `__setitem__` and `__delitem__`.

You must redefine them also.

I can suggest look at OrderedDict implementation.