# Override dict class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, overriding

I'm trying to override `dict` class in a way that is compatible with standard `dict` class. How I can get access to parent `dict` attribute if I override `__getitem__` method?

```
class CSJSON(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, Key : str):
       Key = Key + 'zzz' # sample of key modification for app use
       return(super()[Key])
```

Then I receive error:

```
'super' object is not subscriptable.
```

If I use `self[Key]` then I get infinite recursive call of `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly invoke `__getitem__`, syntax techniques like `[Key]` don't work on `super()` objects (because they don't implement `__getitem__` at the class level, which is how `[]` is looked up when used as syntax):

```
class CSJSON(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, Key : str):
       Key = Key + 'zzz' # sample of key modification for app use
       return super().__getitem__(Key)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, working from `collections.UserDict` or `abc.MutableMapping` might be less painful than directly subclassing `dict`. There are some good discussions here about the options: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148602/9872253), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390997/9872253), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)

> How I can get access to parent dict attribute if I override
> **getitem** method?

More experienced users here seem to prefer MutableMapping, but UserDict provides a convenient solution to this part of your question by exposing a `.data` `dict` you can manipulate as a normal dict.