# How to define self-made object that can be unpacked by `**`?

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

Today I'm learning using `*` and `**` to unpack arguments.
I find that both `list`, `str`, `tuple`, `dict` can be unpacked by `*`.
I guess because they are all iterables. So I made my own class.

```
# FILE CONTENT
def print_args(*args):
    for i in args:
        print i

class MyIterator(object):
    count = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        while self.count < 5:
            yield self.count
            self.count += 1
        self.count = 0

my_iterator = MyIterator()

# INTERPRETOR TEST
In [1]: print_args(*my_iterator)
0
1
2
3
4
```

It works! But how to make a `mapping` object like `dict` in python so that `**` unpacking works on it? Is it possible to do that? And is there already another kind of `mapping` object in python except `dict`?

---

PS:
I know I can make an object inherit from `dict` class to make it a mapping object. But is there some key `magic_method` like `__iter__` to make a mapping object without class inheritance?

---

PS2:
With the help of @mgilson's answer, I've made an object which can be unpacked by `**` without inherit from current mapping object:

```
# FILE CONTENT
def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
    for i, j in kwargs.items():
        print i, '\t', j

class MyMapping(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if int(key) in range(5):
            return "Mapping and unpacking!"

    def keys(self):
        return map(str, range(5))

my_mapping = MyMapping()
print_kwargs(**my_mapping)

# RESULTS
1   Mapping and unpacking!
0   Mapping and unpacking!
3   Mapping and unpacking!
2   Mapping and unpacking!
4   Mapping and unpacking!
```

Be aware, when unpacking using `**`, the key in your mapping object should be type `str`, or TypeError will be raised.

Comment: You can use the `collections` module's [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) `collections.Mapping` and `collections.MutableMapping` to define your own mapping classes that don't inherit from `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any mapping can be used.  I'd advise that you inherit from [`collections.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) or `collections.MutableMapping`<sup>1</sup>.  They're abstract base classes -- you supply a couple methods and the base class fills in the rest.

Here's an example of a "frozendict" that you could use:

```
from collections import Mapping

class FrozenDict(Mapping):
    """Immutable dictionary.

    Abstract methods required by Mapping are
    1. `__getitem__`
    2. `__iter__`
    3. `__len__`
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._data = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
```

And usage is just:

```
def printer(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

d = FrozenDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
printer(**d)
```

<sup>To answer your question about which "magic" methods are necessary to allow unpacking -- just based on experimentation alone -- in Cpython a class with `__getitem__` and `keys` is enough to allow it to be unpacked with `**`.  With that said, there is no *guarantee* that works on other implementations (or future versions of CPython).  To get the guarantee, you need to implement the full mapping interface (usually with the help of a base class as I've used above).</sup>

In python2.x, there's also [`UserDict.UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html) which can be accessed in python3.x as `collections.UserDict` -- However if you're going to use this one, you can frequently just [subclass from `dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394572/748858).

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that as of Python3.3, those classes were moved to the`collections.abc` module.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define unpacking:

```
def unpack(**kwargs): 
    """
    Collect all keyword arguments under one hood
    and print them as 'key: value' pairs
    """
    for key_value in kwargs.items(): 
       print('key: %s, value: %s' % key_value)
```

Now, the structure: two built-in options available are [collections.abc.Mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) and [collections.UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html?highlight=userdict#collections.UserDict). As there's another answer exploring highly-customizable `Mapping` type,  I will focus on `UserDict`: `UserDict` can be easier to start with if all you need is a basic dict structure with some twist. After definition, underlying `UserDict` dictionary of is also accessible as `.data` attribute.

1.It can be used inline, like so:

```
from collections import UserDict
>>> d = UserDict({'key':'value'})

>>> # UserDict makes it feel like it's a regular dict
>>> d, d.data
({'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'})
```

Breaking `UserDict` into key=value pairs:

```
>>> unpack(**d)
key: key, value: value
>>> unpack(**d.data) # same a above
key: key, value: value
```

2.If subclassing, all you have to do is to define self.data within `__init__`. Note that i expanded the class with additional functionality with (self+other) 'magic' methods:

```
class CustomDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, dct={}):
        self.data = dct

    def __add__(self, other={}):
        """Returning new object of the same type
           In case of UserDict, unpacking self is the same as unpacking self.data
        """
        return __class__({**self.data, **other})

    def __iadd__(self, other={}):
        """Returning same object, modified in-place"""
        self.update(other)
        return self
```

Usage is:

```
>>> d = CustomDict({'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'})
>>> d
{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> type(d), id(d)
(<class '__main__.CustomDict'>, 4323059136)
```

Adding other dict (or any `mapping` type) to it will call `__add__`, returning new object:

```
>>> mixin = {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'}
>>> d_new = d + mixin # __add__
>>> d_new
{'key': 'value', 'a': 'aaa', 'key2': 'value2', 'b': 'bbb'} 
>>>type(d_new), id(d_new)
(<class '__main__.CustomDict'>, 4323059248) # new object
>>> d # unmodified
{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

In-place modification with `__iadd__` will return the same object (same id in memory)

```
>>> d += {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'} # __iadd__
>>> d
{'key': 'value', 'a': 'aaa', 'key2': 'value2', 'b': 'bbb'}
>>> type(d), id(d)
(<class '__main__.CustomDict'>, 4323059136)
```

Btw, i agree with other contributors that you should also be familiar with `collections.abc.Mapping` and brethren types. For basic dictionary exploration  UserDict has all the same features and does not require from you to override abstract methods before becoming usable.

Comment: I'm not quite understand what does the `2.` statement mean. Could you explain it with more explicit statements?

Comment: "The need for this class [UserDict] has been largely supplanted by the ability to subclass directly from dict (a feature that became available starting with Python version 2.2)." - https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html

Comment: @Moberg -- That's true.  I find it interesting that it managed to migrate into `collections` for python3.x... I would have thought they'd just cut it out completely. . .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8601389/1256112 that is exactly what OP was looking for.