# Dictionary type that can be used to return value:key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am working on a program where I have a dictionary `dict['key'] = value`, but I would also like to be able to use `dict['value']` and have it return the `key`.

Are there any reversible data structures like this in Python?

I was thinking of adding all of the opposites to my dictionary because all of my relations are 1:1, but I don't think that would be as efficient because I would have twice as many entries as I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863935/a-data-structure-for-11-mappings-in-python), I think your only option is double entries.

Comment: @LukasR If it has been asked before, the correct procedure is to flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh sorry, never did that before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A data-structure for 1:1 mappings in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863935/a-data-structure-for-11-mappings-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276237/4387299  here's TwoWayDict()  (internally consists of two dictionaries)

Comment: the problem here is that key should be hashable, while value may be of any type (e. g. a `list`, it is not hashable and cannot be used as a key)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any bidirectional map in python's standard collection library, but you can take a look at the [bidict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict) package:

```
>>> from bidict import bidict
>>> b = bidict(k='v')
>>> b['k']
'v'
>>> b.inv['v']
'k'
```

Answer (score 2):

For a single-reverse lookup like this, just use

```
[k for k in dict if dict[k] == v]
```

If you use this back-tracking usually, the common way to do it would be to create a reverse dictionary (note that in that case more than one key per value will result in lossy process) -

```
rev_dict = {v: k for k, v in dict.items()}
```

Finally, you might also consider handling your data as tuples of length 2 - like

```
data = [(a, b), (c, d)]
```

if one item does not depend on the other.