# reverse mapping of dictionary with Python

Tags: python, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inverse dictionary lookup - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568673/inverse-dictionary-lookup-python)

If I have a dictionary named ref as  follows

```
ref = {}
ref["abc"] = "def"
```

I can get "def" from "abc"

```
def mapper(from):
    return ref[from]
```

But, how can I get from "def" to "abc"?

```
def revmapper(to):
    ??????
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you do this often, you'll want to build a reverse dictionary:

```
>>> rev_ref = dict((v,k) for k,v in ref.iteritems())
>>> rev_ref
{'def': 'abc'}

>>> def revmapper(to):
...    return rev_ref[to]
```

If it's rare, and you don't care if it's inefficient, do this:

```
>>> def revmapper(to):
...    for k,v in ref.iteritems():
...      if v == to: return k
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this wouldn't be possible with this dict `d = {'a':[1, 2, 3]}`

Comment: @razpeitia : For the reverse dictionary, that's true, but it would work with `d = {'a':(1,2,3)}`, and it wouldn't work if multiple keys had the same values... using the inefficient method will always, unfortunately - inefficiently.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a reverse dictionary:

```
revdict = dict((v,k) for k,v in ref.items())
```

then look up what you want:

```
assert revdict["def"] == "abc"
```

Note this won't work if two keys map to the same value.

Comment: +1 for simplicity, although iteritems would be faster in this case.

Comment: Remember, that `.items` is the [only method in Python3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458567/1908115). Faster and more memory efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict(map( lambda a:[a[1],a[0]], d.iteritems() ))
```

Comment: There is no reason to use map+lambda ever. See the other solutions for how to build a list comprehension or generator expression.

Comment: @aaron: what's the reason that map+lambda is inferior to the others? i assume there's some internal optimizations going on that make it different? how is (k,v)for... better than map(lambda... ?

Comment: 1) no function call overhead. 2) much, much easier to read, especially when there's unpacking involved.

Comment: cool, thanks. but regarding "no reason to use map+lambda ever", do you mean just in this case, or is this a general case? is there anything that "statement for array" can't do that map(lambda) can?