# How to *lazily* iterate on reverse order of keys in OrderedDict?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'd like to iterate on an `OrderedDict` in reverse order.

I.e. reverse the order of:

```
for k, v in my_ordered_dict.iteritems():
   # < do stuff >
```

So far I've gotten a non-lazy version, by reversing a list:

```
for k, v in list(my_ordered_dict.iteritems())[::-1]:
   # < do stuff >
```

Any ideas how to make it better?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/3221487/461887

Comment: @sayth, its a different question

Comment: `reverse()` isn't lazy - it needs to evaluate the whole `iterable` to return it in reverse order, `for k, v in reversed(my_ordered_dict.iteritems())` is about the best you can do.

Comment: @AChampion, in that case `reversed(my_ordered_dict.iteritems())` is equivalent to `list(my_ordered_dict.iteritems())[::-1]`?

Comment: No, this creates 2 lists, one for `list()` and one for `[::-1]` vs. just one for `reversed(...)`

Comment: @AChampion, I think you are mistaken. It looks like OrderedDict has the `__reversed__` method implemented

Comment: TIL: that makes `reversed()` an even better option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use `reversed` on the dict it should evaluate lazily:

```
for k, v in ((k, my_ordered_dict[k]) for k in reversed(my_ordered_dict)):
    .....
```

**How does this work?**

The  key element here is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), which is evaluated lazily.  So this will lazily evaluate over the keys of the ordered dict, and then return a `tuple` of the key and the `dict` value when needed.

**I only need to support python 3:**

In python 3, `dict.items()` is now a view and is evaluated lazily. Thus the above can be simplified to:

```
for k, v in reversed(my_ordered_dict.items()):
```

While Python 2.7 does have a `viewitems()` method, Python 2.7 OrderedDict views do not support the `__reversed__` hook that `reversed` needs to reverse non-sequences.

Comment: could you simplify this further to `for k, v in reversed(my_ordered_dict.items()):` ?

Comment: And why wouldn't `for k, v in reversed(my_ordered_dict.iteritems())` work for Py2?

Comment: @AChampion: `reversed` doesn't accept iterators. (`viewitems` won't work either, because Python 2 OrderedDict views don't support `__reversed__`.)

Comment: Good point. Then `for k in reversed(my_ordered_dict): v = my_ordered_dict[k] ...`, as `OrderedDict` does have `__reversed__()` Py2.

Answer (score -2):

You could for in range with the values and then subtract from the number of values.

```
items = my_ordered_dict.iteritems()
max_index = len(items)

for i in range(max_index):
    object = items[max_index - i - 1]
```

Comment: In Python 2.7—which it looks like you're using—`max_index = len(items)` -> `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`. In Python 3, using `my_ordered_dict.items()` results in `TypeError: 'odict_items' object does not support indexing` for the line `object = items[max_index - i - 1]`.