# index python dictionary by value

Tags: python, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inverse dictionary lookup - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568673/inverse-dictionary-lookup-python)

Is there a built in way to index a dictionary by value in Python.

e.g. something like:

```
dict = {'fruit':'apple','colour':'blue','meat':'beef'}
print key where dict[key] == 'apple'
```

or:

```
dict = {'fruit':['apple', 'banana'], 'colour':'blue'}
print key where 'apple' in dict[key]
```

or do I have to manually loop it?

Comment: Be warned that there is no restriction that the `values` be unique in the `dict`, only the `keys`. What happens when you have two identical keys in your dict?

Comment: @Hooked Do you mean "two identical values"?

Comment: @root45 yes I mean identical "values" not "keys", sorry about that. Something like: `A = {1:'foo',2:'foo'}`. What is the inverse of `foo` supposed to return here?

Comment: I suppose a list of keys should be returned in that case. good point though.

Comment: @Ferguzz: Wrote you an answer which works in all cases and returns a list of keys so that duplicates are handled properly.

Comment: @casperOne: I don't agree. This problem is a more complex than the "duplicate"

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_dict = {'fruit':'apple','colour':'blue','meat':'beef'}
print [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if value == 'apple']
```

The code above is doing almost exactly what said you want:

> print key where dict[key] == 'apple'

The list comprehension is going through all the key, value pairs given by your dictionary's [`items` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), and making a new list of all the keys where the value is 'apple'.

As Niklas pointed out, this does not work when your values could potentially be lists. You have to be careful about just using `in` in this case since `'apple' in 'pineapple' == True`. So, sticking with a list comprehension approach requires some type checking. So, you could use a helper function like:

```
def equals_or_in(target, value):
    """Returns True if the target string equals the value string or,
    is in the value (if the value is not a string).
    """
    if isinstance(target, str):
        return target == value
    else:
        return target in value
```

Then, the list comprehension below would work:

```
my_dict = {'fruit':['apple', 'banana'], 'colour':'blue'}
print [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if equals_or_in('apple', value)]
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to search the values not the keys.

Comment: @Amjith Yeah, I had a brain fart. It's been fixed.

Comment: Doesn't work in the more general second example

Comment: Rather than checking for string type, I'd check for list type, which is less likely to change, otherwise your function will not work for integer values, for example. Also, you should use `isinstance` instance of comparing `type()`s

Comment: The issue with checking for a `list` type is that you no longer can check for membership in a set. Where the correct answer falls is up to the OP. You're definitely right about `isinstance` though. I'll update.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to manually loop it, but if you'll need the lookup repeatedly this is a handy trick:

```
d1 = {'fruit':'apple','colour':'blue','meat':'beef'}

d1_rev = dict((v, k) for k, v in d1.items())
```

You can then use the reverse dictionary like this:

```
>>> d1_rev['blue']
'colour'
>>> d1_rev['beef']
'meat'
```

Comment: You should at least mention what the last line does?

Comment: @bernie: It's not obvious to OP, otherwise he wouldn't ask. A simple "builds the reverse dictionary (value->key)" would be enough, but without anything, this is a bit confusing

Comment: that wouldn't work with the second example because lists are mutable, and so therefore can't be used as dictionary keys.

Comment: if dict is large, use `.iteritems()` instead

Comment: @bernie: Only in Python 2. As it stands, this works in *all* versions of Python (even <2.7), which is nice

Comment: This won't work if the value is a list. Lists are not hashable.

Comment: It would also not work if as expected if lists *were* hashable

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements are more complex than you realize:

- You need to handle both list values and plain values
- You don't actually need to get back a key, but a *list of keys*

You could solve this in two steps:

1. normalize the dict so that every value is a list (every plain value becomes a single-element)
2. build a reverse dictionary

The following functions will solve this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def normalize(d):
    return { k:(v if isinstance(v, list) else [v]) for k,v in d.items() }

def build_reverse_dict(d):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for k,values in normalize(d).items():
        for x in values:
            res[x].append(k)
    return dict(res)
```

To be used like this:

```
>>> build_reverse_dict({'fruit':'apple','colour':'blue','meat':'beef'})
{'blue': ['colour'], 'apple': ['fruit'], 'beef': ['meat']}
>>> build_reverse_dict({'fruit':['apple', 'banana'], 'colour':'blue'})
{'blue': ['colour'], 'apple': ['fruit'], 'banana': ['fruit']}
>>> build_reverse_dict({'a':'duplicate', 'b':['duplicate']})
{'duplicate': ['a', 'b']}
```

So you just build up the reverse dictionary once and then lookup by value and get back a list of keys.

Comment: I think there is a typo at `res[x]` as you've never defined `x`.

Comment: @Hooked: Thanks, indeed I had edited to make it shorter and broke it by doing so...