# Performance of inverse dictionary mapping

Tags: python, dictionary

What would be the most efficient way to get all dict items with `value == 3` and create a new dict?

Here is what I have thus far:

```
d = {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, ...}
new_d = {}
for item in d:
    if d[item] == 3:
        new_d[item] = d[item]
```

Is there a more efficient, simpler way to do this? Perhaps using a map?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568673/inverse-dictionary-lookup-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

```
new_d = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if v == 3}
```

Note that you should call `d.iteritems()` in Python 2.x to avoid creating an unnecessary list.

---

As you can see from the [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) tests below, this solution is more efficient:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> d = {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}
>>>
>>> timeit('''
... new_d = {}
... for item in d:
...     if d[item] == 1:
...          new_d[item] = d[item]
... ''', 'from __main__ import d')
5.002458692375711
>>>
>>> timeit('new_d = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if v == 1}', 'from __main__ import d')
4.844044424640543
>>>
```

It is also a lot simpler, which is always good.

Comment: I get that this is simpler, but is it more efficient?

Comment: If the OP needs to do this for multiple values he may want to make an inverse mapping: `d_inverse = {};for k, v in d.items():d2.setdefault(v, []).append(k)`.  This would be slower for one value, but likely faster for multiple values.