# How to retrieve value from Python dictionary based upon match of list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have following dict and would like to get a key from it based upon list of values:

```
d = {
'Mot': [5250, 1085, 1085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Dek': [0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Nas': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Ost': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Suk': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3156, 1320, 450, 0, 0, 0],
'Tas': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 0, 0],
'Sat': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6551, 5000]
}
    dz = [[5250, 1085, 1085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I tried to adopt get() method without any success (returning this error: unhashable type: 'list'; the same happened when I tried to have numpy's array instead returning: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'):

```
tN= []
for index, element in enumerate(dz):
    tN.append(dict((v,k) for k,v in dict_res.items()).get(element))
```

Is there any way how to retrieve the values from dictionary like that?

Comment: You've put your dict on back-to-front.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568673/inverse-dictionary-lookup-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
d = {
'Mot': [5250, 1085, 1085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Dek': [0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Nas': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Ost': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Suk': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3156, 1320, 450, 0, 0, 0],
'Tas': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 0, 0],
'Sat': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6551, 5000]
}

dz = [[5250, 1085, 1085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

keys = [key for elem in dz for key, value in d.items() if elem==value]
print(keys)
```

Output:

```
['Mot', 'Dek']
```

**UPDATE:**

Modified code so that you get the right order of keys. In case of:

```
dz = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6551, 5000],
    [5250, 1085, 1085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

the output is:

```
['Sat', 'Mot', 'Dek']
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted above by Vasilis G. unfortunately reorders the returned values so in case of having:

```
dz = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6551, 5000],
    [5250, 1085, 1085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

It outputs:

```
['Mot', 'Dek', 'Sat']
```

For cases one needs to know the true order of values in the list, this might be a better choice:

```
keys = []
for i in dz:
    keys.append(list(d.keys())[list(d.values()).index(i)])
#using list comprehension:
#keys = [list(d.keys())[list(d.values()).index(i)] for i in dz]

print(keys)
```

It prints:

```
['Sat', 'Mot', 'Dek']
```