# compare values from a list with values from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary contains lists of values and a list:

```
dict={'first':45, 'second':30, 'third':56}
list= [30,45]
```

I want to compare the value in the dictionary with the list and a match to add to a new dictionary after that, remove from the old dict all the values that are in the new dict: I'm doing something like this:

```
    def get_sessions(self, talks):
      result_sessions = {}
      for k, v in self.sessions.items():
          for i in talks:
            if v == i:
                result_sessions[k] = v
      for k, v in result_sessions.items():
         del self.sessions[k]
     return result_sessions
```

Maybe you know a more elegant solution? any help?

Comment: So Is the current approach giving you the desired output? Is the question about optimization?

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: It looks like you want something based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568673/inverse-dictionary-lookup-in-python

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
d ={'first':45, 'second':30, 'third':56}
lst = [30,45]

result_sessions = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v in lst}
d = { k : d[k] for k in set(d) - set(result_sessions) }

print(result_sessions)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'second': 30, 'first': 45}
{'third': 56}
```