# if-elif-else statement (>10 lines), how to shorten it? Can we use dictionary as an alternative?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a function for budgeting. This part will assign a category for the input item from a user.

The function works but when I come back and look at my code. I wonder how to make this if-elif-else statement shorter.

My **objective** of this part is to **get the category name for the input item. If the input is not listed there, it should be labeled as "other"**

```
desc = input("what have you spent on? ")

if desc in ['cloth', 'watch', 'shoes', 'shirt', 'pants','skirt', 'dress', 'hat']:
    cat = 'shopping'
elif desc in ['lidl', 'kaufland', 'food', 'veggies', 'meat', 'eggs', 'milk']:
    cat = 'food & grocery'
elif desc in ['meals', 'drink','coffee','bakery', 'cake']:
    cat = 'bar & restaurants'
elif desc in ['bus', 'flight','train','transport','car']:
    cat = 'transport & car'
elif desc in ['rent']:
    cat = 'rent'
elif desc in ['withdraw', 'cash']:
    cat = 'cash'
elif desc in ['ATM']:
    cat = 'ATM'
elif desc in ['accommodation','room','hostel','hotel']:
    cat = 'travel'
elif desc in ['internet']:
    cat = 'household & utilities'
elif desc in ['rossmann', 'dm']:
    cat = 'healthcare & drug'     
elif desc in ['donation']:
    cat = 'giving'       
else:
    cat = 'other'
```

I've researched and tried some solutions but I don't know how to make it work.
I've been trying to use a dictionary (like below) but I can't get it right.

```
desc=input("what have you spent on? ")
cat_dict = {'shopping': ['cloth', 'watch', 'shoes', 'shirt', 
                         'pants','skirt', 'dress', 'hat', 'H&M', 'C&A', 'Zalando'],
            'food & grocery': ['lidl', 'kaufland', 'food', 
                               'veggies', 'meat', 'eggs', 'milk'],
            'bar & restaurants':['meals', 'drink','coffee','bakery', 'cake'],
            'transport & car':['bus', 'flight','train','transport','taxi'],
            'rent':['rent'],
            'cash':['withdraw', 'cash'],
            'ATM':['ATM'],
            'travel':['accommodation','room','hostel','hotel'],
            'household & utilities':['internet'],
            'healthcare & drug':['rossmann', 'dm'],
            'giving' :['donation']
           } 
for key, val in cat_dict.items():
    if desc in val:
        category = key
        return category
    else:
        category='other'
        return category
```

I want to it return the 'key' as the category.
But, for example, if I enter 'taxi' it returns 'other' instead of 'transport & car'.

---

Thanks all for your help! I'll report back later <3

Comment: Consider "inverting" this dictionary so you can look up which attributes apply to which things. This is best done with code so you can keep your original structure more organized.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/483666/11082165, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2568673/11082165

Comment: Indeed, a dictionary like `{"cloth":"shopping", "watch":"shopping", ..., "meals":"bar & restaurants", ...}` with repeated values for category may be easier to maintain and add more items to, and can simplify your look ups to something like `category = cat_dict[desc]`

Comment: You are returning "category" in both the cases. You should return only if desc in val. And if category is still None, then return category

Comment: You almost got it! You just need to adapt your if else block in the for loop of the second one.
The else should not be within the for loop at all. Just remove it and have the return "other" at the end (after the loop ends).

Comment: Invert your lookup as others have suggested `cat_dict2 = {value: key for key, values in cat_dict.items() for value in values}`. Now you can do `print(cat_dict2.get("accommodation", "other"))`

Comment: Invert dictionary `cat_from_item = {item: cat for cat, arr in cat_dict.items() for item in arr}` and use like `category = cat_from_item['hotel']`

Answer (score 0):

To invert your cat_dic, if an item can only belong to a single category:

```py
inv_cat_dict = {}
for k,v in cat_dict.items():
    for x in v:
        inv_cat_dict.update([(x,k)])

print(inv_cat_dict)
# output: {'cloth': 'shopping', 'watch': 'shopping', 'shoes': 'shopping', 'shirt':...
```

... or if you want to consider the possibility that an item could belong to several categories:

```py
inv_cat_dict = {}
for k,v in cat_dict.items():
    for x in v:
        inv_cat_dict.setdefault(x, []).append(k)

print(inv_cat_dict)
# output: {'cloth': ['shopping', 'rent'], 'watch': ['shopping', 'travel'],...
```