# Python - Compare 2 files and output differences

Tags: python, file, compare, output, diff

I'm aiming to write a script that will compare each line within a file, and based upon this comparison, create a new file containing the lines of text which aren't in the second file.

For example;

```
**File 1:** 

Bob:20 
Dan:50 
Brad:34 
Emma:32 
Anne:43

**File 2:**

Dan:50
Emma:32
Anne:43
```

**The new output (File 3):**

```
Bob:20
Brad:34
```

I have some idea of how this needs to be done, but not exactly:

```
def compare(File1,File2):
   with open(File1, "a") as f1:
       lines = f1.readlines()
       string = line.split(':')
   with open(File2, "a") as f2:
       lines = f2.readlines()
       string2 = line.split(':')
       if string[0] == string[1]:
           with open("newfile2.txt", "w") as f3:
            ....
```

I think I need something along the lines of this and then to compare the string[0] from each line of each file but I'm really clueless from this point.

Any help would be extremely welcomed.

Comment: Do you know of the unix tool `diff`? You might be trying to reinvent the wheel here…

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544331/quickly-find-differences-between-two-large-text-files

Comment: Are the files already ordered?  Is the number behind the colon irrelevant?

Comment: The files will have up to 10,000 lines of text and the number next to the names will always be random.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
def compare(File1,File2):
    with open(File1,'r') as f:
        d=set(f.readlines())


    with open(File2,'r') as f:
        e=set(f.readlines())

    open('file3.txt','w').close() #Create the file

    with open('file3.txt','a') as f:
        for line in list(d-e):
           f.write(line)
```

You need to compare the readlines set and find out lines that are not present in file2. You can then append these lines to the new file.

Comment: Thanks - could you amend this as so it compares the files only based on the name?

Comment: I didn't understand.. Elaborate please?

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I'd like it so the lines are compared in the file based only on the name, not the number. For example, file 1 could have Bob:5, and file two have Bob:3 - but since the names are still the same, it doesn't output this into file3.

Comment: I think something like line.split(':')[0] would be needed? but I'm unsure on where this would go.

Answer (score 0):

If there is difference in line, the program will print it.

```py
with open("H:/Ast/Hpa.java", encoding="utf8") as f:
    with open("G:/Soft_install/Hpa.java", encoding="utf8") as fe:
        for line in f:
            for linefe in fe:
                if (line != linefe):
                    print(line)
                    break
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some explanation as to why this is a solution to OP's question. This will help OP and future visitors to the site who come across this question. Code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Thanks! --From Review.

Comment: This does not work when an entire line is missing from a file. For example: if the new file has an added line.   It only prints a changed line.