# How do I compare two text files in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to write a coincidence analysis code comparing two text files in python.The code I have written is as follows:

```
datafile1 = np.loadtxt('some_file_1.txt')
datafile2 = np.loadtxt('some_file_2.txt')
SNR1 = datafile1[:,0]
peak1 = datafile1[:,1]
m11 = datafile1[:,2]
m12 = datafile1[:,3]
SNR2 = datafile2[:,0]
peak2 = datafile2[:,1]
m21 = datafile2[:,2]
m22 = datafile2[:,3]

f = open('out_file.txt', 'w')
F = datafile[:,1].astype(int)         
for i in F:         
    for j in range(i-40,i+41):
        if (m11[j] == m21[i] and m12[j] == m22[i]):
          f.write(SNR1[j] + " " + peak1[j] + " " + m11[j])
          f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

The code should take a value from "peak2", then compare it to all the values of "peak1". If the value of "peak1" is equal to or within a difference of +/- 40 from "peak2" and if the value of "m11" is equal to "m21" and if "m12" is equal to "m22", it should write the values of "peak1", "m11" and "m12" in a text file. The error I get is that "index 477358 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10000
". I realize the error is regarding the indices, but I cannot figure out how to correct it in a way that works.

Comment: What does "compare" mean to you? What exactly is the code supposed to do? Please show a short example of what might appear in the files, *exactly* what should happen as a result, *exactly* what happens instead, and explain how that is different or wrong.

Comment: Edited the original post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Compare 2 files and output differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213525/python-compare-2-files-and-output-differences)

Comment: Haha this is exactly opposite of what I'm asking. In my case, the code should pick the other three data points in the code(from the link you sent).

Answer (score 0):

if i get you well, this is how you compare two files in Python.

```
with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('some_file_2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')
with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Let me know if you are answered

Comment: Yes, this is how it usually works, but since I also require to list values which have the same values for other columns AND are valid within a tolerance of +/-40, I don't know how to change this code to include that.