# Can not configure output in quoted text

Tags: python

Sir need some help.

I think it's an easy task but I cannot configure it.
I want to compare two text files & output the differences in quoted text.

I tried this post-https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216365/12031112 & it's working fine, but I cannot
get output in quoted text.

```
def compare(File1,File2):
    with open(File1,'r') as f:
        d=set(f.readlines())


    with open(File2,'r') as f:
        e=set(f.readlines())

    open('file3.txt','w').close() #Create the file

    with open('file3.txt','a') as f:
        for line in list(d-e):
           f.write(line)
File1 = 'Updatedfile1.txt'
File2 = 'Rawfile2.txt'
compare(File1,File2)
```

for example:  In text file it was without a quote & each line ie

```
boofx.com

uooos.com

jiooq.com
```

But want output like below in file3.txt:

```
"boofx.com",
"uooos.com",
"jiooq.com",
"zcrcd.com",
"jeoce.com",
"xcoxc.com",
"cdfaq.com",
```

& in the last line without a comma(,).
Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you add double quotes and comma to the lines read before writing them to the file?

Comment: Thanks, sir. I implement the idea you share & it works.