# switching keys and values in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Say I have a dictionary like so:

```
my_dict = {2:3, 5:6, 8:9}
```

Is there a way that I can switch the keys and values to get:

```
{3:2, 6:5, 9:8}
```

Comment: Are the values unique?  Are the values hashable?

Comment: What about `my_new_dict = dict(zip(my_dict.values(), my_dict.keys()))`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

For Python 3:

```py
my_dict2 = {y: x for x, y in my_dict.items()}
```

For Python 2, you can use

```py
my_dict2 = dict((y, x) for x, y in my_dict.iteritems())
```

Comment: `.iteritems()` is not valid on Python 3.x...

Comment: @JBernardo: Fixed thanks I forgot about that

Comment: another correction - doing the dictionary comprehension you suggest `{(y, x) for x, y in dic_cols_w.items()}` returns a set, not a dictionary. You would still need to wrap this in a `dict(...)` to get a dictionary

Comment: @tsando: I think you have read my answer incorrectly. I have `{y:x ...`

Comment: How would you do this if the values were a list of items and each item in the list should be a key?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Perhaps ask a new question or look for another answer?

Comment: In Python 3.6, it (2nd solution) still gives an error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`. Any workaround? Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the future readers: for Python 3.x, use `item()` instead of `iteritems()` i.e. `my_dict2 = {y:x for x,y in my_dict.items()}`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/483833/10358768

Answer (score 14):

```
my_dict = { my_dict[k]:k for k in my_dict}
```

Comment: Clean answer this one.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {2:3, 5:6, 8:9}

new_dict = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    new_dict[v] = k
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this code (trivially modified) from the accepted answer at [Python reverse / invert a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping):

```
dict((v,k) for k, v in my_dict.iteritems())
```

Note that this assumes that the values in the original dictionary are unique.  Otherwise you'd end up with duplicate keys in the resulting dictionary, and that is not allowed.

And, as @wim points out, it also assumes the values are hashable.  See [the Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html) if you're not sure what is and isn't hashable.

Answer (score 6):

maybe:

`flipped_dict = dict(zip(my_dict.values(), my_dict.keys()))`

Comment: this is probably not safe as it relies on key and value ordering, although it happened to work for me.

I like JBernardo/GWW's answer(s).

Comment: It's probably better to use `iterkeys` and `itervalues`

Comment: That's safe if the dict isn't changed during the operation. I liked because you did it without a comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

First of all it is *not* guaranteed that this is possible, since the values of a dictionary can be unhashable.

In case these are not, we can use a functional approach with:

```
reversed_dict = dict(map(reversed, original_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the condition that the values are all unique will not hold, in which case, the answers above will destroy any duplicate values.

The following rolls the values that might be duplicates up into a list:

```
from itertools import count
dict([(a,[list(d.keys())[i] for i,j in zip(count(), d.values())if j==a in set(d.values())])
```

I'm sure there's a better (non-list-comp) method, but I had a problem with the earlier answers, so thought I'd provide my solution in case others have a similar use-case.

P.S. Don't expect the dict to remain neatly arranged after any changes to the original! This method is a one-time use only on a static dict - you have been warned!

Answer (score 2):

If the values are not unique this will collide the key space in conversion. 
Best is to keep the keys in list when switching places

below handles this -

```
RvsD = dict()
for k,v in MyDict.iteritems():
    RsvD.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

Function:

```
def inverse_dict(my_dict):
    updated_dict = {}
  
    for i in my_dict:
        updated_dict[my_dict[i]] = [i]

    return updated_dict
```

Main():

```
def main():
    year = {'day': 15, 'month': 3, 'year': 2019}
    print(inverse_dict(year))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ouput:

```
{15: ['day'], 3: ['month'], 2019: ['year']}
```

Answer (score 1):

If values are not unique in the dictionary, then you can map keys to that value. Here an example of how to do it using defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict


def reverse_dict(data: dict) -> dict:
    rd = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in data.items():
        rd[v].append(k)
    return rd


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from collections import Counter

    data = "aaa bbb ccc ddd aaa bbb ccc aaa"
    c = Counter(data.split())
    print(c)
    # Counter({'aaa': 3, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 2, 'ddd': 1})
    rd = reverse_dict(c)
    print(rd)
    # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {3: ['aaa'], 2: ['bbb', 'ccc'], 1: ['ddd']})
```