# Matching a word in Pandas column and when creating a new column based on the match

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, csv, numpy, python-2.6

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns and a dict with key and values as a lists. in the df one column represents a description, I need to look at this description and check if it matches one of the values in the list of the dict.

This is an extract from the dict:

```py
clothing_types = {'T-Shirt': ['t-shirt', 'shirt', 'tee'],
          'Tank Top': ['tank top', 'mesh', 'top', 'tank'],
          'Socks': ['socks'],
          'Hat': ['cap'],
          'Trainers': ['trainers', 'snickers', 'shoes', 'furylite 
          contemporary'}
```

This is the column:

```
0       UNDER ARMOUR LADIES FLY-BY STRETCH MESH TANK TOP
1            UNDER ARMOUR LADIES SPEEDFORM NO SHOW SOCKS
2            UNDER ARMOUR LADIES SPEEDFORM NO SHOW SOCKS
3                     UNDER ARMOUR LADIES PLAY UP SHORTS
4             REEBOK LADIES CLASSIC LEATHER MID TRAINERS
5      UNDER ARMOUR MENS Spring Performance Oxford SHIRT
6       UNDER ARMOUR LADIES HEATGEAR ALPHA SHORTY SHORTS
7                                 ADIDAS LADIES PRO TANK
8                REEBOK LADIES ONE SERIES V NECK T-SHIRT
9                              REEBOK LADIES DF LONG BRA
10                     NIKE LADIES BASELINE TENNIS SKIRT
11              UNDER ARMOUR MENS ESCAPE 7" SOLID SHORTS
12      UNDER ARMOUR LADIES FLY-BY STRETCH MESH TANK TOP
```

I can do the comparison through the normal for loops:

```py
for item in self.original_file['Product Description'].tolist():
    found = False
    for item_type, type_descriptions in clothing_types.items():
        for description in type_descriptions:
            if description.upper() in item.upper():
                # print(item_type, item)
                found = True
                break

    if not found:
        print('NOT FOUND', item)
```

And have tried to do it with the np.where:

```py
for item_type, type_descriptions in clothing_types.items():
    for description in type_descriptions:
        self.original_file['Category'] = np.where(description.upper() in self.original_file['Product Description'], item_type, 'None')
```

but it replaces the values with the last value comparison which makes the column value always None

***The expectation is that if the let say "SHIRT" is in the description "T-Shirt" (which is a key of the dict) will be populated in the new column - Category***

Comment: What do you do if there is a match? What is the expected output? A column of True/False?

Comment: I need the key of the dictionary populated, so if there is a match for shirt -> T-Shirt will be populated

Answer (score 1):

We can check with `str.contains` if we find any matches. If we get a hit, we fill in the `key` of the dictionary, else nothing. Finally we remove all whitespaces and the matches as a column:

```
matches = [np.where(df['Product Description'].str.contains('|'.join(v), case=False), 
                    k, 
                    '') for k, v in clothing_types.items()]

matches_df = pd.DataFrame(matches).T.sum(axis=1).to_frame('Matches')

df = df.join(matches_df)
```

**Output**

```
                                  Product Description   Matches
0    UNDER ARMOUR LADIES FLY-BY STRETCH MESH TANK TOP  Tank Top
1         UNDER ARMOUR LADIES SPEEDFORM NO SHOW SOCKS     Socks
2         UNDER ARMOUR LADIES SPEEDFORM NO SHOW SOCKS     Socks
3                  UNDER ARMOUR LADIES PLAY UP SHORTS          
4          REEBOK LADIES CLASSIC LEATHER MID TRAINERS  Trainers
5   UNDER ARMOUR MENS Spring Performance Oxford SHIRT   T-Shirt
6    UNDER ARMOUR LADIES HEATGEAR ALPHA SHORTY SHORTS          
7                              ADIDAS LADIES PRO TANK  Tank Top
8             REEBOK LADIES ONE SERIES V NECK T-SHIRT   T-Shirt
9                           REEBOK LADIES DF LONG BRA          
10                  NIKE LADIES BASELINE TENNIS SKIRT          
11           UNDER ARMOUR MENS ESCAPE 7" SOLID SHORTS       Hat
12   UNDER ARMOUR LADIES FLY-BY STRETCH MESH TANK TOP  Tank Top
```

Answer (score 0):

So this works, but not sure if this is the best solution

```
for i in self.original_file.index:
    for item_type, type_descriptions in clothing_types.items():
        for description in type_descriptions:
            if description.upper() in self.original_file.iloc[i]['Product Description'].upper():
                self.original_file.at[i, 'Category'] = item_type
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should switch between keys and values in your clothing_types dict like that

```
lothing_types2 = dict(list(itertools.chain(*[[(y_, x) for y_ in y] for x, y in clothing_types.items()])))
```

([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305518/switching-keys-and-values-in-a-dictionary-in-python))

Then, create a function to search per row, if there is any word in the new dict you were created:

```
def to_category(x):
    for w in x.lower().split(" "):
        if w in clothing_types2:
            return clothing_types2[w]
    return None
```

Finally, apply the method on the column and save the result to a new one:

```
df["Category"] = df["clothing"].apply(to_category)
```