# Transpose values and key in a dictionary when values are not unique

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping, reverse

I want to change keys to values in a python dictionary, but the values in the original dictionary are not unique.

Here is what I have:

```
year_person = {2000: ‘Linda’, 2001: ‘Ron’, 2002: ‘Bruce’, 2003: ‘Linda’, 2004: ‘Bruce’, 2005 ‘Gary’, 2006: ‘Linda’}
```

This is what I want to change it to:

```
person_year = {‘Linda’: 2000, ‘Ron’: 2001, ‘Bruce’: 2002, ‘Linda’, 2003: ‘Bruce’, 2004 ‘Gary’, 2005: ‘Linda’: 2006}
```

When I tried to convert it using a for loop, I only got one matching pair for each person.

Comment: You can't do that. Each key must be unique. You could create a list of all values for each key.

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/q/483666/989121

Answer (score 11):

You can also do it with a defaultdict:

```
year_person = {2000: 'Linda', 2001: 'Ron', 2002: 'Bruce', 2003: 'Linda', 2004: 'Bruce', 2005: 'Gary', 2006: 'Linda'}

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in year_person.items():
    d[v].append(k)

print dict(d)
>>> {'Bruce': [2002, 2004], 'Linda': [2000, 2003, 2006], 'Ron': [2001], 'Gary': [2005]}
```

Comment: If one is going to use a `defaultdict`, it should be converted to a regular `dict` when the function that implements this returns. `defaultdict` has the annoying property of implicitly turning missed attribute hits into insertions. I.e. it creates bugs when that's not what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's why I converted it in the `print` statement.

Comment: that's a not exactly transparent way of illustrating the potential problem.

Comment: You can use dictionary comprehension for this. It might help you
dict_two = {value:key for key,value in dict_one.iteritems()}

Answer (score 7):

Just to present some other options and information that may be missing from the current answers:

If you are sure your values are unique, and therefore can become keys, the simplest method is a dict comprehension:

```
year_person = {2000: 'Linda', 2001: 'Ron', 2002: 'Bruce', 2003: 'Linda', 2004: 'Bruce', 2005: 'Gary', 2006: 'Linda'}
person_year = {key: value for (value, key) in year_person.items()}
```

Of course, in your case, they are not, so this doesn't work (as it only gives the last value found):

```
person_year = {'Bruce': 2004, 'Linda': 2006, 'Ron': 2001, 'Gary': 2005}
```

Instead, we can use a nested list comp inside a dict comp:

```
{key: [value for value, check_key in year_person.items() if check_key==key] for key in year_person.values()}
```

Giving us:

```
{'Bruce': [2002, 2004], 'Linda': [2000, 2003, 2006], 'Ron': [2001], 'Gary': [2005]}
```

This works, but isn't efficient due to having to loop over the entire dictionary for every entry. A much better solution is [the `defaultdict` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036839/722121) given by alan, which requires only a single loop.

Answer (score 3):

What you wan't to achieve is technically not feasible. Key to a dictionary cannot be duplicate because if so you cannot uniquely index a dictionary with a key.

What you can do, is to create a dictionary of (key,value) pair where value is the list of all items which has the same key. To achieve it you can do something as follows

```
>>> person_year={}
>>> [person_year.setdefault(v,[]).append(k) for (k,v) in year_person.iteritems()]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> person_year
{'Bruce': [2002, 2004], 'Linda': [2000, 2003, 2006], 'Ron': [2001], 'Gary': [2005]}
>>>
```

Note, if you are only interested in the key value pair and not a dictionary per se' you can just store as a list of tuples as follows

```
>>> [(v,k) for k,v in year_person.iteritems()]
[('Linda', 2000), ('Ron', 2001), ('Bruce', 2002), ('Linda', 2003), ('Bruce', 2004), ('Gary', 2005), ('Linda', 2006)]
>>>
```

Comment: I would describe this as unpythonic - a list comprehension is designed to be used to create a list, not to process data. In this case, a much cleaner, clearer solution is the one alan gave with a defaultdict. Also it's worth noting ``iteritems()`` only exists pre-Python 3.x, after that, just use ``items()``.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, `defaultdict` is unnecessary here and doing it as a list comprehension sacrifices readability (though that's not generally the case). Unless profiling indicates that this is really a bottleneck, I would do it as follows:

```
def invert_to_lists(dct):
    inverted_dict = {}
    for key in dct:
        inverted_dict.setdefault(dct[key], []).append(key)
    return inverted_dict
```

`defaultdict` is one more complication. Using `setdefault` is fine in this case because it only needs to be typed out once. After going through the rigmarole of importing and instantiating a `defaultdict`, you will have typed more than making the one call to `setdefault`.

Comment: So what's the problem? Why the downvote?