# Reverse elements in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python reverse / inverse a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping)

Say I have the following.

```
D = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
```

How would I reverse each element so I get

```
inverseD = {1:'a',2:'b',3'c'}
```

Comment: irrelevant, but I still don't understand those people who downvote a user's legit confusion on some topic, even given his/her stack life has only been a month.

Comment: Agreed. A downvote for a newcomers question should at least be accompanied by an explanation for the downvote and/or a suggestion on how to improve the question.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use a dict comprehension (Python `2.7+` and `3.0+`):

```
D = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
inverse = {v: k for k, v in D.items()}
print(inverse)
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Comment: heh, exactly same answer. I had to go through the captcha check, that's why I'm late. I'll delete my answer. +1.

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.6 and earlier (no dict comprehension):

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
inverse_dict = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
```

This assumes that the values of dict `d` are hashable, for example, it won't work on this dictionary:

```
>>> d={'l':[],'d':{},'t':()}
>>> inverse_dict = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

You will also run into problems if the *values* of the original dict are not unique, e.g.

```
>>> d={'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
>>> dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
{1: 'd', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. Couldn't find it in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mata's answer if you have Python2.7+ otherwise use mhawke's answer.

Inverting a dict like this only works properly if all the values of the source dict are unique and hashable

If the values are hashable, but not unique you can make a dict with having lists for the values instead