# Python - VERY basic 'encryptor'

Tags: python, string, replace

Me and a guy at work decided to try and make a basic python program that would 1) jumble a string & 2) un-jumble the string. The idea was that we can send each other absolute rubbish.

My first attempt (I am awful at this):

```
x = ("This is the text")
x1 = x.replace("a","r")
x2 = x1.replace("b","w") 
x3 = x2.replace("c","z")  #Do this for the whole alphabet 
print(x3)                 #both upper and lower case
```

Then do the same but back to front to unscramble.... It works but its also longggggg....

Code from this article: http://gomputor.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/search-replace-multiple-words-or-characters-with-python/ suggests creating a method as follows:

```
def replace_all(text,dic):
    for i,j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i,j)
    return text

reps = {'a':'r','b':'w','c':'z'} #for the whole alphabet again (yawn)
x = ("This is the text")

txt = replace_all(x, reps)
print(txt)
```

Will this work? I have seen iteritems() get bad press elsewhere??

Comment: Where did you read bad things about `iteritems()`? It's just fine. Also, I don't really understand your question - didn't you try your code? Why not find out if it works?

Comment: Check out `string.translate`

Comment: Hypothetical situation: your encryptor replaces A with B, and B with C. Then "ABBA" translates to "CCCC", and "BABA" _also_ translates to "CCCC". Your decrypter won't be able to distinguish between the two!

Comment: @PauloScardine Actually *all* of the letters would have to be shifted for this to be caesar cipher

Comment: This is called a [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) and is easy to break based on letter frequency.

Comment: Paulo: would this essentially be the lowest form of encoding then? (Thanks for the link!)

Comment: @Mattrugbymad, I think I have provided something lower.

Comment: Use steganography in photos of kittens. Everyone loves kitten jpegs in the mail.

Comment: ... and the inability to cut and paste the text to verify or search for related info makes them even more joyful.

Comment: The "lowest" form of encryption would be a [shift cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). It has no more than 25 possible keys.

Comment: Also... HOORAY CRYPTOGRAPHY!! :) Read lots of crypto books! Crypto is awesome! (little plug here for some [cryptanalysis scripts](https://github.com/2rs2ts/py-crypttools) I wrote a few years ago for a Crypto class...)

Answer (score 2):

iteritems returns a list of key, value pairs from the dictionary. The only reason to watch out for iteritems is that it was removed in python 3.0 because dict.items now does the same thing.

As for the code, its functionally correct (except that x should be my_text), though the encryption strength isn't very high.

There are many algorithms that use simpler encryption key methods (your reps dictionary) and produce higher quality encryption.  If you are working in python why not use a simple library like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt to get a higher quality encryption/decryption?

Comment: Thanks for this! I am new to programming so this is a great help. The encryption side of it isn't necessarily important. It just started as a conversation based around 'can we email each other through work without the IT guys spying on us'. A half hearted suggestion turning into a solid Friday afternoon muck-around!  I also edited the code, should have been x not my_text

Comment: Answer updated.  There are many simple-to-use encryption libraries available for python.  I've included the link to one, it would save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: If you want to just mess the IT guys heads a little, just send random strings a data back of forth.

Comment: @dansalmo: He doesn't want to mess with them, he wants to have semi-secure communication.  Though, to your point, sending random noise messages among the actual messages would certainly increase security.

Comment: If the IT folk are even reading your messages, there is a very good chance they will be able to decrypt your messages (a substitution cipher is not secure against a six-year-old). But now you know this, and the IT folk do not know that you know this, thus you still have a great way to mess with them.

Answer (score 2):

Drum roll please.....

```
>>> msg="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> cyphertext = ' '.join(w[1:]+'-'+w[0]+'ey' for w in msg.split())
>>> cyphertext
'he-Tey uick-qey rown-bey ox-fey umps-jey ver-oey he-tey azy-ley og-dey'
>>> ' '.join(w[-3] + w[:-4] for w in cyphertext.split())
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Note that the non-standard treatment of "the" and "quick" along with the possible confusion as to the "ey" vs "ay" suffix enhances security.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in Python 2 rot13 is a built in codec:

```
>>> 'This is the text'.encode('rot13')
'Guvf vf gur grkg'
>>> 'Guvf vf gur grkg'.decode('rot13')
u'This is the text'
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

Answer (score 0):

why not use string.translate

```
import string
tab = string.maketrans(string.ascii_letters,string.ascii_letters[13:]+string.ascii_letters[:13])
message = "hello world!"
encoded = message.translate(tab)
tab_decode = string.maketrans(string.ascii_letters[13:]+string.ascii_letters[:13],string.ascii_letters)
print encoded.translate(tab_decode)
```

with string.translate you can define any mapping you want

```
key = "lkj234oiu1563lop|.)(*&^%$#@!" #note key must be as long as your alphabet(in this case 52)
mapping = (string.ascii_letters,key)
tab_encode = string.maketrans(*mapping)
encoded = "hello world".translate(tab_encode)
tab_decode = string.maketrans(*list(reversed(mapping)))
decoded = encoded.translate(tab_decode)
```

another thing you could do is base64 encoding (**note this is not encryption**, however it is probably about as hard to crack as a simple ceasar cipher)

```
import base64
decoded = "Hello World!!!"
encoded = base64.b64encode(decoded)
print encoded
print base64.b64decode(encoded)
```

Comment: Sorry guys it was a bit rushed. Unfortunately I'm still at work so its all jotted down on paper and in notepad. 

Kevin sorry they are just an example, I have a set of 'proper' key:value's set up

Tim: I saw something earlier on a forum with someone hoping it would be removed from a future release (I think the comment was old)

Comment: translating back transforms to upper case

Comment: just in this case ... the point is you can use any mapping you want with translate

Comment: But it has to translate back to the original.  1) jumble a string & 2) un-jumble the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution that you can use to learn from. You can use it to both encode and decode you messages. Just specify what you want to do and then type in your message. A blank line indicates that you are finished with your message and signals for the requested transformation to take place.

```
import string

PLAIN_TEXT = string.ascii_letters
CIPHER_TEXT = 'kWFUsDYeAxolSLTwChgNJtaMvQIzRZVrPEyfiKXGcdBunbqHjpOm'

CIPHER_TABLE = str.maketrans(PLAIN_TEXT, CIPHER_TEXT)
PLAIN_TABLE = str.maketrans(CIPHER_TEXT, PLAIN_TEXT)

def main():
    while True:
        choice = input('Encode or Decode? ').lower()
        if choice:
            if 'encode'.startswith(choice):
                process_text(CIPHER_TABLE)
                continue
            if 'decode'.startswith(choice):
                process_text(PLAIN_TABLE)
                continue
        print('Please try again.')

def process_text(table):
    buffer = []
    while True:
        line = input('> ')
        if not line:
            break
        buffer.append(line.translate(table))
    print('\n'.join(buffer))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want an even better solution, bookmark [Wabol Talk](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Wabol_Talk) and use that to create your messages. You can look at its source and see that it is implemented in Python as well. The program encrypts messages and encodes them in the "Wabol" language. I can also provide a GUI version of the program if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic, very insecure ciphers with which to have fun! By the way, I was googling around and I found some neat slides from [Northeastern University](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/riccardo/courses/csg252-fa06/lecture1.pdf) on basic cryptosystems. Also, I apologize if my lettering habits differ from wiki or anyone else; I just go with my habits.

#### Shift Cipher

The shift cipher has an integer ring (e.g. the letters of the alphabet, A-Z, numbered from 0-25 usually, and we typically call this Z26) and an integer key, let's call it `k`. In order to build this ring, we will use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), basically meaning our numbers will only ever be between 0 and 25 if our modulus, let's call it `n`, is 26.) For any given plaintext letter, let's call it `m`, we can encode it by adding `k` to `m`, modulo `n` - and viola! We have our ciphertext letter, let's call it `c`.

To put it mathematically: `c ≅ m + k (mod n)`. And logically, `m ≅ c - k (mod n)`. To put it programmatically:

```
def encrypt(m, k, n):
    return (m + k) % n

def decrypt(c, k, n):
    return (c - k) % n
```

#### Substitution Cipher

Substitution ciphers are much harder to crack than shift ciphers, but they are still easy to crack using many characteristics of the English language. Google them if you like - but I gotta say, a nice program to help you is [`freq.c`](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~spr/COURSES/CRYPTO/freq.c).

A substitution cipher consists of the same ring, with a mapping of plaintext characters to ciphertext characters. For instance, `A = G, B = Q, C = E, D = T` and so on. A dictionary's really great for this: `k = {'A' : 'G', 'B' : 'Q', ...}`.  If you want to decrypt, you can [invert the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/483833/691859).

```
def encrypt(m, k):
    return k[m]

def decrypt(c, k):
    for key, value in k.items():
        if value == c: return key
```

#### Affine Cipher

This cipher adds modular multiplication to the shift cipher. The key is now a pair `a, b` where `a` must be coprime to `n`, so that it has a modular multiplicative inverse. To encrypt, multiply `m` with `a` (modularly) and then add `b` (modularly). Choosing an `a` which is coprime isn't exactly obvious - basically, you need to make sure that the greatest common divisor of `a` and `n` is 1.

Mathematically: `c ≅ (am + b) mod n` and therefore `m ≅ a^-1(c - b) mod n`. Programmatically:

```
def encrypt(m, a, b, n):
    return (a*m + b) % 25
```

And I'm not going to write a clever solution for finding this modular multiplicative inverse... you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm for this, but for me it's just easier to bruteforce it when n is so small.

```
def getModularMultiplicativeInverse(a, b, n):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if (a * x) % n == 1:
            return x

def decrypt(c, a, b, n):
    return (getModularMultiplicativeInverse(a, b, n) * (c - b)) % n
```

These were just some little examples... less for the code, more for the chatter.

Comment: Thanks! Those slides are interesting as well. What started off as a half hearted office joke is now becoming an obsession