# Ranking values in a Dictionary (and taking care of ex-aequos correctly)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ranking

I would like to rank the values in a dictionary.

For instance, I have this dictionary: `{"A": 10, "B: 3, "C": 8, "D": 3, "E": 2}`
The result should look like: `{"E": 1, "B": 2, "D": 2, "C": 4, "A": 5}`

Please note that `D` is ranked as *fourth* because `B` and `D` are tied at position *two*. Hence, there is no position *three*.

Similar solutions have already been given in other threads, however they did not take into account ex-aequo positions in the traditional way: [Adding a rank to a dict in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641054/adding-a-rank-to-a-dict-in-python) and [Python Ranking Dictionary Return Rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282600/python-ranking-dictionary-return-rank/30282676)

Comment: You want to sort the dict by its values, and then use the sorted indices (+1) as ranking? Well, with the ex-aequo caveat of course.

Comment: hm yes. sort of. but how about ties to achieve the expected result given above (when two have the same value and position)? it seems not trivial to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sort the data in ascending order based on the number, like this

```
>>> data = {"A": 10, "B": 3, "C": 8, "D": 3, "E": 2}
>>> s_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
>>> s_data
[('E', 2), ('D', 3), ('B', 3), ('C', 8), ('A', 10)]
```

Now, for every element processed,

- if it is not the same as the previous element then the rank should be incremented by the number of similar elements processed till now
- if it is the same, then simply count the current element as a similar element

To implement this, initialize few variables, like this

```
>>> rank, count, previous, result = 0, 0, None, {}
```

then keep checking if the current element is not equal to the previous element and if it is true, increment `rank` by the number of times the similar elements occured.

```
>>> for key, num in s_data:
...     count += 1
...     if num != previous:
...         rank += count
...         previous = num
...         count = 0
...     result[key] = rank
```

Now, `result` will have the result you wanted.

```
>>> result
{'D': 2, 'C': 4, 'E': 1, 'B': 2, 'A': 5}
```