# How to get list of keys that share a value with another key within the same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, unique

I have a dictionary of unique keys where some keys share the same value.

For example:

```
D = {'ida':{'key':'1'},'idb':{'key':'2'},'idc':{'key':'3'},'idd':{'key':'3'},'ide':{'key':'4'},'idf':{'key':'4'},'idg':{'key':'4'}}
```

I want a list of keys that share the same value with other keys.

In this case, it would be

```
l = ['idc','idd','ide','idf','idg']
```

However, I want to exclude one key from all sets of keys that share the same value.

For example, I'd like to have the keys

```
l = ['idd','idf','idg']
```

which excludes 'idc' and 'ide'

or it could be

```
l = ['idc','ide','idf']
```

which excludes 'idd' and 'idg'.

Answer (score 1):

If the value appears more than once the list comp will add the key.

```
dup_keys = [k for k in D if sum(D[k] in x for x in D.iteritems()) > 1 ]

['idf', 'idg', 'idd', 'ide', 'idc']

dup_keys[1:]
['idg', 'idd', 'ide', 'idc']
dup_keys[1:-1]
['idg', 'idd', 'ide']
```

`if sum(D[k] in x for x in D.iteritems()) > 1` checks the value appears `> 1` times.

To ignore certain keys add some `and` condition, I am not sure on what basis you want to ignore the keys.

Comment: So the thing is that it doesn't matter which key out of the set of keys that have the same value is excluded. Only as long as one of them is excluded is fine.

Comment: just slice the list, how do you end up with 3 and not 4 keys though?

Answer (score -3):

```
# aDictionary = { <aKey>: <aValue>, ... }             python dictionary constructor

  aDictionary = { 'ida': '1', \                  
                  'idb': '2', \
                  'idc': '3', \
                  'idd': '3', \
                  'ide': '4', \
                  'idf': '4', \
                  'idg': '4'  \
                  }

# the OP used aDictionaryOfDictionaries construction instead.
# aDictOfDICTs = {'ida':{'key':'1'},'idb':{'key':'2'}, ... }

# The algorithmisation of the processing task is different.

# for aDictionary, a inverseDictionary may be assembled 
# to hold for each <aValue>,
# a referring <aKey>, incl. those, where are more than one primary <aKey>-s,
# ( stored asListOfPrimaryKEYs or aSetOfPrimaryKEYs ), which len() is easy to test
```

**A fair & robust solution for a proper anInverseDICTIONARY construction**
can be found at "Fast functional solution for non-bijective maps (**values not unique**):" in >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235665/3666197

Beware, not all posts yield a robust solution there.

**Finally**

```
>>> aListOfDUP_KEYs = [ anInvDictKEY for anInvDictKEY in anInverseDICTIONARY.keys() if ( len( anInverseDICTIONARY[anInvDictKEY] ) > 1 )  ]

    [ 3, 4 ]

''' as anInverseDICTIONARY = { 1: set( [ 'ida' ] ),
                               2: set( [ 'idb' ] ),
                               3: set( [ 'idd', 'idc' ] ),
                               4: set( [ 'idg', 'idf', 'ide' ] )
                               }
'''
```

**Remove** whichever DUP-e from **anInverseDICTIONARY** via aDUP_KEY, or from the original **`aDictionary`** by a list comprehension

```
>>> [ aDictionary.pop( anInverseDICTIONARY[aDUP_KEY].pop() ) for aDUP_KEY in aListOfDUP_KEYs ]

    [ 'idd', 'idf' ]
```

Comment: what is this supposed to be?