# Get dictionary of all dictionary keys that share the same list value and their common value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists and want to combine the keys which share duplicate lists into a seperate list within a dictionary that also contains the original list that they all share.

I have tried to use existing solutions that work for hashable type such as when the dictionary just contains strings as the values. Relevant SO question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517504/how-to-get-list-of-keys-that-share-a-value-with-another-key-within-the-same-dict). Each time I attempt any of these solutions or any others I have tried using similar techniques all result in an unhashable type error.

Here is an example of what my dictionary looks like.

```
exampledict = {'FOO': [1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 9], 'BAR': [1, 2], 'BAZ': [1, 2], 'ABC': [1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 9]}
```

The correct output should be two dictionaries:

```
finaldict1 = {'keys': ['BAR', 'BAZ'], 'value': [1, 2]}
finaldict2 = {'keys': ['FOO', 'ABC'], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 9]}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: In link given by you and your question difference is that value is list in your case and value is a dictionary in already answered question. This makes a difference. You will have to compare if values(lists) are equal or not

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

final_dicts = [{'keys': [e[0] for e in v], 'value': k} for k, v in groupby(sorted(exampledict.items(), key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1))]
finaldict1 , finaldict2 = final_dicts

print(finaldict1)
print(finaldict2)
```

output:

```
{'keys': ['BAR', 'BAZ'], 'value': [1, 2]}
{'keys': ['FOO', 'ABC'], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 9]}
```

in this case, it just happens that you have 2 dicts, but you can use the final_dicts variable as you want

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

**Ex.**

```
from collections import defaultdict
exampledict = {'FOO': [1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 9], 'BAR': [1, 2], 'BAZ': [1, 2], 'ABC': [1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 9]}
newMap = defaultdict(set)
for key, value in exampledict.items():
    newMap[tuple(value)].add(key)

result = [{'keys':list(newMap[x]),'value':list(x)} for x in newMap ]
print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'keys': ['FOO', 'ABC'], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 9]}, {'keys': ['BAR', 'BAZ'], 'value': [1, 2]}]
```