# Python dictionary key assign

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I've created a dictionary from a tuple, but can't seem to find an answer as to how I'd switch my keys and values without editing the original tuple. This is what I have so far:

```
tuples = [('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '3')]

dic = dict(tuples)

print dic
```

This gives the output:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': ''1', 'c': '2', 'd': '3'}
```

But I'm looking for:

```
{'1': 'a' 'b', '2': 'c', '3': 'd'}
```

Is there a simple code that could produce this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes: the values are not unique here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP didn't say how he's going to handle them.

Comment: @simonzack: the value for `'1'` is invalid Python syntax, but you *can* see that both `'a'` and `'b'` are grouped there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the value for `'1'` is valid as the syntax catenates the literal strings. But I agree it's probably not what the OP wants

Comment: @gnibbler: Yeah, I was purposefully ignoring that. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters didn't notice the `'a' 'b'` at a glance. Looked like if @Eeconyn didn't mind losing values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a dictionary in a loop, collecting your values into lists:

```
result = {}

for value, key in tuples:
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

The [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) will set and return a default value if the key isn't present. Here I used it to set a default empty list value if the key is not present, so the `.append(value)` is applied to a list object, always.

Don't try to make this a mix of single string and multi-string list values, you'll only complicate matters down the road.

Demo:

```
>>> tuples = [('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '3')]
>>> result = {}
>>> for value, key in tuples:
...     result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
... 
>>> result
{'1': ['a', 'b'], '3': ['d'], '2': ['c']}
```

Comment: Plus eleventy billion to "Don't try to make this a mix of single string and multi-string list values, you'll only complicate matters down the road."

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
first = itemgetter(0)
second = itemgetter(1)
d = dict((x, [v for _, v in y]) for x, y in groupby(sorted(tuples, key=second), key=second)
```

`groupby` groups the tuples into a new iterator of tuples, whose first element is the unique second item of each of the original, and whose second element is *another* iterator consisting of the corresponding first items. A quick example (pretty-printed for clarity):

```
>>> list(groupby(sorted(tuples, key=second), key=second)))
[('1', <itertools._grouper object at 0x10910b8d0>), 
 ('2', <itertools._grouper object at 0x10910b790>),
 ('3', <itertools._grouper object at 0x10910b750>)]
```

The sorting by the same key used by `groupby` is necessary to ensure all like items are grouped together; `groupby` only makes one pass through the list.

The subiterators consist of tuples like `('1', 'a')`, so the *second* value in each item is the one we want to add to the value in our new dictionary.