# How to reference a dictionary key passed into a function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like this:

```
phone_numbers = {'Ted': '555-222-1234', 'Sally': '555-867-5309'}
```

I'd like function that returns both the key and the value passed to it, e.g.:

```
>>> phonebook(phone_number['Ted'])
Ted's phone number is: 555-222-1234
```

In pseudocode, the function would be:

```
def phonebook(number): 
    print("{}'s phone number is: {}".format(
        number.key(),  # Not a real dictionary method!
        number.value())  # Also not a real dictionary method!
```

Is there a way to do this without a lot of major back-end rewriting of types and classes?

Comment: You *can't*; `phone_number['Ted']` is evaluated to `'555-222-1234'` **before** `phonebook` gets called. You could do e.g. `phonebook(phone_number, 'Ted')`, though.

Comment: ... at which point you could just use `phone_numbers.get()`.

Comment: This is part of a teach-myself-Python project. Is a dictionary the wrong datatype to be using for this kind of function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to pass both the dictionary and the name that you want to lookup:

```
>>> phone_numbers = {'Ted': '555-222-1234', 'Sally': '555-867-5309'}
>>> def phonebook(dct, name):
...     print("{}'s phone number is: {}".format(name, dct[name]))
...
>>> phonebook(phone_numbers, 'Ted')
Ted's phone number is: 555-222-1234
>>>
```

Doing `phone_number['Ted']` simply returns the string phone number that is associated with the key `'Ted'` in the dictionary.  Meaning, there is no way to trace this string back to the dictionary it came from.

Answer (score -1):

here is your answer :

```
def phonebook(phonenumber):
    for name, number in phone_numbers.items():
        if(number = phonenumber):
            print("{}'s phone number is: {}".format(name, number)
            return
```

Comment: This answer demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of the benefits of a dictionary, and the use of scope to access variables is somewhat unwise.

Comment: I know, but it does respond the question.
I think the method phonebook is like a reverse phone lookup...

Comment: Reverse `phone_numbers` and pass it in as a parameter; then it's a trivial `O(1)` lookup in local scope.

Comment: great idea the reverse phone_numbers. but iCodez asked how to do it with a method : def phonebook(number) and a dictionary based on the user for key. if the reverse dictionnary is not available than only a full scan will give you the name linked to a number.

Comment: This is going to take a really long time at two years per comment. I'm out.

Comment: a really long time :). someone is busy. great for you ;)
if you have no response let someone else respond. bye

Comment: for someone interesed on reverse dictionnary. here a link to a old question about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping