# Python reverse / inverse a mapping (but with multiple values for each key)

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping, inverse

This is really a variation on this question, but not a duplicate:

[Python reverse / invert a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483666/992834)

Given a dictionary like so:

`mydict= { 'a': ['b', 'c'], 'd': ['e', 'f'] }`

How can one invert this dict to get:

`inv_mydict = { 'b':'a', 'c':'a', 'e':'d', 'f':'d' }`

Note that values span uniquely under each key.

**Note**: I previously had syntax `map = ...` and `dict = ...` Reminder not to use `map` and `dict` as they are built-in functions, see excellent comments and answers below :)

Comment: `map` is a keyword, don't use as a dictionary name.

Comment: I changed to wording to dict as a result

Comment: @KevinLee, `dict` is a keyword too :-))

Comment: @ForceBru thanks I'm not thinking Python enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> my_map = { 'a': ['b', 'c'], 'd': ['e', 'f'] }
>>> {value: key for key in my_map for value in my_map[key]}
{'c': 'a', 'f': 'd', 'b': 'a', 'e': 'd'}
```

---

The above seen dictionary comprehension is functionally equivalent to the following looping structure which populates an empty dictionary

```
>>> inv_map = {}
>>> for key in my_map:
...     for value in my_map[key]:
...         inv_map[value] = key
... 
>>> inv_map
{'c': 'a', 'f': 'd', 'b': 'a', 'e': 'd'}
```

**Note:** Using `map` shadows the built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function. So, don't use that as a variable name unless you know what you are doing.

---

**Other similar ways to do the same**

**Python 3.x**

You can use [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), like this

```
>>> {value: key for key, values in my_map.items() for value in values}
{'c': 'a', 'f': 'd', 'b': 'a', 'e': 'd'}
```

We use `items()` method here, which would create a view object from the dictionary which would give key value pairs on iteration. So we just iterate over it and construct a new dictionary with the inverse mapping.

**Python 2.x**

You can use [`dict.iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) like this

```
>>> {value: key for key, values in my_map.iteritems() for value in values}
{'c': 'a', 'b': 'a', 'e': 'd', 'f': 'd'}
```

We don't prefer `items()` method in 2.x, because it will return a list of key-value pairs. We don't want to construct a list just to iterate and construct a new dictionary. That is why we prefer `iteritems()`, which returns an iterator object which gives a key value pair on iteration.

**Note:** The actual equivalent of Python 3.x's `items` would be Python 2.x's [`viewitems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) method, which returns a view object. Read more about the view object in the official documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

---

### `iter*` vs `view*` methods in Python 2.x

The main difference between `iter*` functions and `view*` functions in Python 2.x is that, the view objects reflect the current state of the dictionary. For example,

```
>>> d = {1: 2}
>>> iter_items = d.iteritems()
>>> view_items = d.viewitems()
```

now we add a new element to the dictionary

```
>>> d[2] = 3
```

If you try to check if `(2, 3)` (key-value pair) is in the `iter_items`, it will throw an error

```
>>> (2, 3) in iter_items
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

but view object will reflect the current state of the dictionary. So, it will work fine

```
>>> (2, 3) in view_items
True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mp = { 'a': ['b', 'c'], 'd': ['e', 'f'] }

pm={}
for x in mp.iterkeys():
    for d in mp[x]:
        pm[d]=x

print pm
```

Output:

> {'c': 'a', 'b': 'a', 'e': 'd', 'f': 'd'}

*Note:* a dictionary is an *unordored* data structure, so the result may not be ordered as you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the unordered reminder, I ended up using the library `natsort` to sort my dictionary.