# Replacing the value of a Python dictionary with the value of another dictionary that matches the other dictionaries key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

At the moment I have two dictionaries

```
dictionary1 = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
dictionary2 = {'value1': 'AAA', 'value3': 'CCC'}
```

I want to replace the values of `dictionary1` with the values from `dictionary2` which with the example above would produce the following output

```
{'key1': 'AAA', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'CCC'}
```

From other examples I have read I think that I should begin my code as follows:

```
for key, value in dictionary1.iteritems():
    if value ==
```

Now I am unsure as to the best method to cycle through the other dictionary to find if the value from dictionary1 matches a key from dictionary2.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but I'd recommend giving your dictionaries new names -- If I saw the name `list1`, I might assume it was a `list` rather than a `dict` ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I changed them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> dictionary1 = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
>>> dictionary2 = {'value1': 'AAA', 'value3': 'CCC'}
>>> {k: dictionary2.get(v, v) for k, v in dictionary1.items()}
{'key3': 'CCC', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'AAA'}
```

Here, `dict2.get(v, v)` will try to get the value corresponding to the value `v` from `dict2`. If it is not found, the default value (second parameter), `v` itself will be returned.

**Note 1:** What you have in question, are called dictionaries, not lists.

**Note 2:** If you are using Python 2.7, then you might want to use `dict1.iteritems` or `dict1.viewitems` instead of `dict1.items`. The reason is explained, elaborately, with examples, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29633896/1903116).

Comment: This is not working for me. I don't know why. It should, but it isn't.

Comment: This should be `{k: dictionary2.get(k, v) for k, v in dictionary1.items()}`. Because the `get` method accepts the key as the first argument

Answer (score 7):

A cross lookup in the second list with a fallback to the default value if it doesn't exist is the way to go.

```
>>> {key : list2.get(value, value) for key, value in list1.items()}
{'key3': 'CCC', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'AAA'}
```

[get(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) allows you to lookup for the key in the dictionary and if the value is not present, the default value is returned. The default value should be the same value you would pursue to search in the second dictionary.

Comment: The most `python` way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to do a second for loop over your second dictionary until you find a matching value.

```
for key, value in list1.iteritems():
    for key2 in list2:
         if value == key2:
             list1[key] = list2[key2]
             break
```

Comment: runtime can be  proportional to size(list1)*size(list2) , so it's not the good way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

For an in place change :

```
for k,v in dictionary1.items():
    if v in dictionary2 : dictionary1[k]=dictionary2[v]
```

it's faster than creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this solution pretending to present dict comprehension solution with a more complex condition:

I have faced a similar situation but the goal was replacing matched keys in different dicts where dict has **multiple values** for each key-value pair. After a long try-error time with conditionals dict comprehensions, here my solution:

```
>>> result = {k: [dic2.get(v, v) for v in v] for k, v in dic1.iteritems()}
```

Figure:

```
>>> dic1 = {'key1': ['value1', 'value12', 'value13'], 'key2': ['value2', 'value21'] 'key3': ['value3']}
>>> dic2 = {'value1': 'path_AA', 'value12': 'path_BB',  'value2': 'path_DD', 'value21': 'path_EE', 'value3': 'path_FF'}
>>>
>>> result = {'key1': ['path_AA', 'path_BB'], 'key2': ['path_DD', 'path_EE'], 'key3': 'path_FF'}
```