# converting a dictionary to another one

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary, the keys are integer values and the values are a list of strings.
I want to make it vice versa, the string become key and integers become values. 
Like:

first design:

```
{1:["a"], 2:["a","b"], 3:["a"], 4:["b", "cd"], 6:["a","cd"]}
```

second design:

```
{"a": [1,2,3,6], "b":[2,4], "cd":[4,6]}
```

any clue? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for [Invert Dictionary-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633848/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping-but-with-multiple-values-for-each-key)

Comment: @MohammedKashif that one's different in that the values in the lists are unique.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach would be to create a `defaultdict` that provides an empty list for new keys, and then for each list in your current dict, create a key for each element and append the original dict key to the new list:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

orig = {1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['a'], 4: ['b', 'cd'], 6: ['a', 'cd']}
d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in orig.items():
    for string in v:
        d[string].append(k)

# d = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 6], 'b': [2, 4], 'cd': [4, 6]}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the love of one-liners (note: heavily inefficient!):

```
d2 = {val: [key for key in d if val in d[key]] for lst in d.itervalues() for val in lst}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code

```
first_map = {1: ["a"], 2: ["a", "b"], 3: ["a"], 4: ["b", "cd"], 6: ["a", "cd"]}
second_map = {}
for key, value in first_map.items():
    for i in value:
        if i in second_map:
            second_map[i].append(key)
        else:
            second_map[i] = [key]
print(second_map)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
z = {1:["a"], 2:["a","b"], 3:["a"], 4:["b", "cd"], 6:["a","cd"]}
d = dict()

for k, v in z.iteritems():
    for i in v: 
        if i in d: 
            d[i].append(k)
        else:   
            d[i] = [k]
```

Using `iteritems()` over `items()` is a little better because the former creates a generator in Python 2.

Comment: Maybe better ```iteritems```, since OP indicates Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1= {1:["a"], 2:["a","b"], 3:["a"], 4:["b", "cd"], 6:["a","cd"]}
dict2= {}
for key, value in dict1.items():
   for val in value:
       if val in dict2:
           dict2[val].append(key)
           dict2[val]= list(set(dict2[val]))
       else:
           dict2[val]= [key]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

second_dict = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in first_dict.items():

    for item in value:

        second_dict[item].append(key)
```