# Invert dictionary/directed graph with edge labels

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to invert for example this dictionary:

```
{1: {1: '[]', 2: '[1]'}, 2: {1: '[]', 3: '[1]'}, 3: {1: '[]'}}
```

Imagine that this is a directed graph with vertices `1, 2, 3` and labelled edges like `1 -> 1` with label `'[]'`, represented in dictionary form by `1: {1: '[]'`. The labels don't have to be strings, they can just be lists.

I want to reverse the edges and keep the labels as they are.
The output i want is:

```
{1: {1:'[]', 2:'[]', 3:'[]'}, 2: {1:'[1]'}, 3:{2:'[1]'}}
```

I saw some methods like [Python reverse / invert a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping) but they all work for simpler dictionaries having no "labels".

Comment: What is the desired output? What have you tried? Dies it work?

Comment: Be little bit more specific what you want as a output. write down the output for the example mentioned by you.

Comment: Edit: now there is the output I want. I invert the edges of the labelled graph and I keep the labels as before.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `{1: {1: '[]', 2: '[]', 3: '[]'}, 2: {1: '[1]'}, 3: {2: '[1]'}}`? Note the `2` in the last sub-dict.

Comment: @tobias_k Completely right! Edited, now it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate the sub-dictionaries and the keys in those and add them to a new dictionary with first and second key reversed.

```
d = {1: {1: '[]', 2: '[1]'}, 2: {1: '[]', 3: '[1]'}, 3: {1: '[]'}}
p = {}
for from_, subdict in d.iteritems():
    for to, value in subdict.iteritems():
        p.setdefault(to, {})
        p[to][from_] = value
print p
```

Or use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), i.e. `p = collections.defaultdict(dict)`, then you don't need the `p.setdefault(to, {})` line.

Afterwards, `p` is `{1: {1: '[]', 2: '[]', 3: '[]'}, 2: {1: '[1]'}, 3: {2: '[1]'}}`