# Convert a list of words to a list of integers in scikit-learn

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

I want to convert a list of words to a list of integers in scikit-learn, and do so for a corpus that consists of a list of lists of words. E.g. the corpus can be a bunch of sentences.

I can do as follows using  [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer), but is there any simpler way? I suspect I may be missing some CountVectorizer functionalities, as it's a common pre-processing step in natural language processing. In this code I first fit CountVectorizer, then I have to iterate over each words of each list of words to generate the list of integers.

```
import sklearn
import sklearn.feature_extraction
import numpy as np

def reverse_dictionary(dict):
    '''
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping
    '''
    return {v: k for k, v in dict.items()}

vectorizer = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(min_df=1)

corpus = ['This is the first document.',
        'This is the second second document.',
        'And the third one.',
        'Is this the first document? This is right.',]

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

tokenizer = vectorizer.build_tokenizer()
output_corpus = []
for line in corpus: 
    line = tokenizer(line.lower())
    output_line = np.empty_like(line, dtype=np.int)
    for token_number, token in np.ndenumerate(line):
        output_line[token_number] = vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(token) 
    output_corpus.append(output_line)
print('output_corpus: {0}'.format(output_corpus))

word2idx = vectorizer.vocabulary_
print('word2idx: {0}'.format(word2idx))

idx2word = reverse_dictionary(word2idx)
print('idx2word: {0}'.format(idx2word))
```

outputs:

```
output_corpus: [array([9, 3, 7, 2, 1]), # 'This is the first document.'
                array([9, 3, 7, 6, 6, 1]), # 'This is the second second document.'
                array([0, 7, 8, 4]), # 'And the third one.'
                array([3, 9, 7, 2, 1, 9, 3, 5])] # 'Is this the first document? This is right.'
word2idx: {u'and': 0, u'right': 5, u'third': 8, u'this': 9, u'is': 3, u'one': 4,
           u'second': 6, u'the': 7, u'document': 1, u'first': 2}
idx2word: {0: u'and', 1: u'document', 2: u'first', 3: u'is', 4: u'one', 5: u'right', 
           6: u'second', 7: u'the', 8: u'third', 9: u'this'}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is a more direct way, but you can simplify the syntax by using `map` instead of for-loop to iterate over each word.

And you can use `build_analyzer()`, which handles both preprocessing and tokenization, then there is no need to call `lower()` explicitly.

```
analyzer = vectorizer.build_analyzer()
output_corpus = [map(lambda x: vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(x), analyzer(line)) for line in corpus]
# For Python 3.x it should be
# [list(map(lambda x: vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(x), analyzer(line))) for line in corpus]
```

output_corpus:

```
[[9, 3, 7, 2, 1], [9, 3, 7, 6, 6, 1], [0, 7, 8, 4], [3, 9, 7, 2, 1, 9, 3, 5]]
```

**Edit**

Thanks to @user3914041, just using list comprehension might be preferable in this case. It avoids `lambda` thus can be slightly faster than `map`. (According to [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) and my simple tests.)

```
output_corpus = [[vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(x) for x in analyzer(line)] for line in corpus]
```

Comment: I don't think it gets much better than this, I'm not aware of a way to do this using `CountVectorizer`. I prefer the list comprehension syntax though: `[[vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(x) for x in analyzer(line)] for line in corpus]`

Comment: @user3914041Hmm... I agree that list comprehension is preferable in this case

Answer (score 1):

I often use Counter to solve this in python, e.g.

```
from collections import Counter

corpus = ['This is the first document.',
        'This is the second second document.',
        'And the third one.',
        'Is this the first document? This is right.',]
​
#convert to str from list and split
as_one = ''
for sentence in corpus:
    as_one = as_one + ' ' + sentence

words = as_one.split()
​
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(words)
vocab = sorted(counts, key=counts.get, reverse=True)
vocab_to_int = {word: ii for ii, word in enumerate(vocab, 1)}
​
print(vocab_to_int)
```

output:

> {'the': 1, 'This': 2, 'is': 3, 'first': 4, 'document.': 5, 'second':
>   6, 'And': 7, 'third': 8, 'one.': 9, 'Is': 10, 'this': 11, 'document?':
>   12, 'right.': 13}

Comment: Probably a better way to convert the List to a String is: as_one = ' '.join(corpus)

Answer (score 0):

For a given text, the `CountVectorizer` is meant to return a vector that is the count of each word.

E.g. for the corpus:
`corpus = ["the cat", "the dog"]`, the vectorizer will find 3 different words, thus it will output vectors of dimension 3 where "the" would correspond to the first dimension, "cat" to the second one, and "dog" to the third one. For instance, "the cat" would be transformed to [1, 1, 0], "the dog" to [1, 0, 1], and sentences with repeated words would have larger values (e.g. "the cat cat" → [1, 2, 0]).

For what you want to to, you would have a good time with the [Zeugma](https://github.com/nkthiebaut/zeugma/tree/master/zeugma) package. You would just have to do the following (after runnning `pip install zeugma` in a terminal):

```py
>>> from zeugma import TextsToSequences
>>> sequencer = TextsToSequences()
>>> sequencer.fit_transform(["this is a sentence.", "and another one."])
array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]], dtype=object)
```

And you can always access the "index to word mapping: with

```
>>> sequencer.index_word
{1: 'this', 2: 'is', 3: 'a', 4: 'sentence', 5: 'and', 6: 'another', 7: 'one'}
```

From there you can transform any new sentence with this mapping:

```
>>> sequencer.transform(["a sentence"])
array([[3, 4]])
```

I hope it helps!