# Return a dictionary of keys of common values in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to return a dictionary of the keys of the elements in another dictionary which occur more than once.

Example:

```
x = {1:10, 2:12, 3:14, 4:10, 5:14}
```

The answer will return

```
{10:[1,4], 14:[3,5]}
```

Comment: These are values, not elements. Also show us what you've tried already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python reverse / invert a mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution that comes to mind

```
x = {1: 10, 2: 12, 3: 14, 4: 10, 5: 14}

res = {}
for k, v in x.items():
    temp = res.setdefault(v, [])
    temp.append(k)
res = {k: v for k, v in res.items() if len(v)>1}
print(res)  # {10: [1, 4], 14: [3, 5]}
```

I wonder if `itertools.groupby()` can be used here somehow..

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
# python 2.x
x = {1:10, 2:12, 3:14, 4:10, 5:14} 
a = {}

for key, value in x.iteritems():  # x.items() if python 3.x
    a.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

for key, value in x.iteritems():
    if len(value) <= 1
        a.pop(key, None)

print a
```

Comment: take a look at `setdefault()` dictionary method. Allows you to skip the check on the keys.

Comment: Sure sir. I think I haven't written python for past 2 years or so.

Comment: No problem whatsoever. Also please state that the solution is for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {1:10, 2:12, 3:14, 4:10, 5:14} 
res = {}
for k, v in x.iteritems():
    res[v] = res.get(v, [])
    res[v].append(k)

{k: v for k, v in res.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation.