# TypeError: 'int' is not iterable when trying to iterate over a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration, typeerror

I'm somewhat new to python, and I have been trying to find a way to iterate over a dictionary whose keys are as follow:

```
r_alpha: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}
```

lets assume the following:
I have a list and I want to find if the value of the list is in the dictionary key and print the value for that key but this happens:

```
th = [1,2,3]
for item in th:
for keys, values in r_alpha.items():
        if item in keys:
            print(values)
```

I receive the following error, pointing to line 4 (if item in keys:)
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

If I change that list to string values I actually get the keys for the values that are strings like this:

```
th = ['a','b','c']
for item in th:
for keys, values in r_alpha.items():
        if item in values:
            print(keys)
```

**it prints: 1 2 3**

can someone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong? or how can I iterate over the int keys of the dictionary so it returns the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your error is because you are iterating over the keys in a loop, and at each iteration compare the key to some other value using the `in` operator which is meant for membership tests with iterables. Since your keys are integers (not iterables), this will obviously not work.

---

There's no need to iterate over the keys of a dictionary when they support constant time lookup.

```
for item in th:
    if item in r_alpha:
        print(r_alpha[item])
a
b
c
```

Alternatively, you could use `dict.get` to remove the `if` condition.

```
for item in th:
    print(r_alpha.get(item))
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thank you, for the first case where th = [1,2,3] can you also use dict.get()? like what would be a faster way instead of doing the loop.

Comment: @MauricioCastaneda It will only work in the first case. For the second... you'll need to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping or stick to your current implementation.