# how to convert multiple sentences into bigram in python

Tags: python, text-mining, n-gram, countvectorizer

I'm fairly new to python and I would like to convert an array of sentences to bigrams, is there a way to do this? for example

```
X = ['I like u', 'u like me', ...]
```

If ngram = 2 I'm expecting the vocabulary has something like

```
[0: 'I ',
 1: ' l',
 2: 'li',
 3: 'ik',
 4: 'ke',
 5: 'e ',
 6: ' u',
 7: 'u ',
 8: ' m',
 9: 'me'...]
```

so X can be converted to

```
 X_conv = [ '0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6',
            '7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9',....]
```

Is there an functionI can do with countvectorizer?

Comment: why are the list items *wrapped in lists*?

Comment: Also this is a bit broad - what code have you got so far? one sentence to bigrams?

Comment: I think I can only split it within one sentence:[text[i:i+n] for i in range(len(text)-n+1)], but how to apply in a list of many sentences?

Comment: You just need to put that in a function `def ngrams(text, n): return [...goes here... ]`

Comment: sorry that was a typo, corrected

Comment: then you can use a list comprehension to convert all of array into list of ngrams, then the only problem is to number them :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have the function `ngrams`:

```
def ngrams(text, n=2):
    return [text[i:i+n] for i in range(len(text)-n+1)]
```

now applying this to all elements to a list is rather easy:

```
>>> sentences = ['I like u', 'u like me']
>>> processed = [ngrams(sentence, n=2) for sentence in sentences]
>>> processed
[['I ', ' l', 'li', 'ik', 'ke', 'e ', ' u'], 
 ['u ', ' l', 'li', 'ik', 'ke', 'e ', ' m', 'me']]
```

So that is rather easy. To number the ngrams, you could build nested for loops, but it wouldn't look nice.

Instead we can use a trick: `collections.defaultdict`, which will create a new item if it doesn't exist when it is first accessed. We couple this with `itertools.count()` which returns a iterable counter. The `__next__` magic method is a callable that when called the first time returns the first number, then the second and so forth. `defaultdict` will call this method once per each new item

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

reverse_vocabulary = defaultdict(count().__next__)
numbered = [[reverse_vocabulary[ngram] for ngram in sentence]
            for sentence in processed]
print(numbered)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]]
```

Now the reverse vocabulary is the opposite of what you'd want:

```
defaultdict(<...>, {' m': 8, ' u': 6, 'I ': 0, 'li': 2, 'u ': 7, 'e ': 5, 'ke': 4, 'ik': 3, 
                    ' l': 1, 'me': 9})
```

We make an ordinary dictionary of it [by inverting the mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping):

```
vocabulary = {number: ngram for ngram, number in reverse_vocabulary.items()}
```

which results in vocabulary being an ordinary dictionary

```
{0: 'I ', 1: ' l', 2: 'li', 3: 'ik', 4: 'ke', 5: 'e ', 6: ' u', 7: 'u ', 8: ' m', 9: 'me'}
```

Comment: thank you so much!! do you know if there is simplier function that i can do this in sklearn's countvectorizer?