# How to reverse dict when key is bit mask?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to reverse `Flag_to_Marker` during compilation:

```
class FLAG(IntEnum):
    DEFAULT_ZERO = 0b0
    L1 = 0b01
    L2 = 0b10
    RSU = 0b100
    ESCALATED_COMMENTS = 0b1000

    Flag_to_Marker = {L1: 'is_l1', L2: 'is_l2', RSU: 'is_rsu'}
    Marker_to_Flag = {v: k for k, v in Flag_to_Marker.items()}

    def marker(self, flag):
       return self.Flag_to_Marker[flag]

    def flag(self, marker):
       return self.Marker_to_Flag[marker]
```

but I have the following exception when I trying to construct `Marker_to_Flag`: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'`. How to fix that?

I want to have `Marker_to_Flag = {'is_l1': L1, 'is_l2': L2, 'is_rsu': RSU}`

Comment: Do you want `Marker_to_Flag = {v: k for k, v in Flag_to_Marker.items()}` instead?

Comment: I tried, but I got `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python reverse / invert a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping)

Comment: the problem is somewhere we don't see

Comment: You can't define arbitrary data in an `IntEnum`. Define your dictionaries outside of the class. Otherwise python tries to convert them into an integer. Take a look at the documentation - there is also some information about using enums as flags.

Answer (score -2):

```
Marker_to_Flag = {v: k for k, v in Flag_to_Marker.items()}
```

Comment: I tried, but I got `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'`

Comment: I think that error is being generated somewhere else. I ran the code through my interpreter and the dictionary is reversed

Answer (score -2):

1. Your values must be unique.
2. reversed_dict = {y:x for x,y in Flag_to_Marker.items()}