# How to group same Dictionary values together in Python and Count the Value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you print a dictionary in Python where if the value matches another value in the dictionary, they are printed on the same line?

Code:

```
result = {'light':4,'plane':4, 'vehicle':5}

print(result)
```

Current Output:

```
{'light': 4, 'plane': 4, 'vehicle': 5}
```

Expected Output:

```
4 light, plane
5 vehicle
```

How would you also count the frequency of the words as in the expected output? For example, `light + plane` is `2`.

Comment: f.e. this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/485368/7505395 from the dupe (there are some handling grouping for multiple values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
from collections import defaultdict

v = defaultdict(list)
d = {'light':4,'plane':4, 'vehicle':5}

for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    v[value].append(key)
```

This will also work :

```
k = {}

for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    k.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
```

**UPDATE :**
If you want to print it in your desired format :

```
for i, j in v.items():
    print(i,", ".join(l for l in j))
```

O/P will be like :

```
4 light, plane
5 vehicle
```

**UPDATE 2:**
The code to print in the desired format mentioned above is completed below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
v = defaultdict(list)
d = {'light':4,'plane':4, 'vehicle':5}
for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    v[value].append(key)
for i, j in v.items():
    print(i,", ".join(l for l in j))
```

Comment: How would I count the total of all words?

Comment: what you mean by total of all words ? for a list you can use len

Comment: For example, I want to break the code when a certain amount of words is met. Vehicle, light and plane = a total of 3 words.

Comment: if you want the total of all words from main dict you can use `len(d.keys())`