# Inverting dictionary in Python not yielding results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing an assignment that asks me to create a dictionary and then invert it based on "Think Python" book function. The function has to invert my dictionary and turn each list item into separated keys.

I created a dictionary that shows similar soccer players for the sake of the assignment however I thought that my function should be returning the inverted dictionary by now but it isn't.

```
    def soccer():
    splayers = dict()
splayers = {'Ronaldo': 'Messi', 'Buffon': 'Courtois', 'Mbappe': 'Vinicius'}
def invert_dict(splayers):
     inverse = dict()
     for key in splayers:
          val = splayers[key]
          if val not in inverse:
               inverse[val] = [key]
          else:
               inverse[val].append(key)
     return inverse
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Please format the code. Although, it doesn't look like you are actually calling your function anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python reverse / invert a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this somewhat simpler using the setdefault() method.

```
splayers = {'Ronaldo': 'Messi', 'Buffon': 'Courtois', 'Mbappe': 'Vinicius'}
inverted = dict()
for k,v in splayers.items():
    inverted.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
```

You could also do it on a single line using groupby() from itertools but it will be less efficient and not as legible:

```
from itertools import groupby
inverted = { key:list(values) for key,values in groupby(sorted(splayers),lambda x:splayers[x]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>> splayers = {'Ronaldo': 'Messi', 'Buffon': 'Courtois', 'Mbappe': 'Vinicius'}
>> splayers_inv = {value: key for key, value in splayers.items()}
>> splayers_inv
{'Courtois': 'Buffon', 'Messi': 'Ronaldo', 'Vinicius': 'Mbappe'}
```

Comment: If you read his code, he needs to handle the case where two players have the same last name by storing each first name as a list and appending to that list.