# convert a normal sequence dictionary into reversed triply ordered dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert my dictionary to a triply ordered reversed dictionary.

my dictionary is `{1: 1, 3: 3, 5: 6, 6: 6}`

I have already tried using nested dictionaries, but i am not sure how to get the required output.

```
Dict1 = list(Dict)

Dict2['Dict1'] = Dict

print(Dict2)
```

The output should be `{1: {1: [1], 3: [3]}, 2: {6: [5, 6]}}`
if i define a different dictionary, i should get different triply ordered dictionary.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: good example, but can you explain the logic a bit more?

Comment: Please explain with logic how we reach from what you have to `reversed triply ordered dictionary`

Comment: While there is an answer using defualt dict, I suggest checking out this answer to a similar questoin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/485368/6018688 that uses `inv_map.setdefault(v, []).append(k)` and does not rely on defaultdict from collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

orig_d = {1: 1, 3: 3, 5: 6, 6: 6}

new_d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in orig_d.items():
    new_d[v].append(k)

final_d = defaultdict(dict)
for cnt, (k, v) in sorted((len(v), (k, v)) for k, v in new_d.items()):
    final_d[cnt][k] = v

print(dict(final_d))
```

Prints:

```
{1: {1: [1], 3: [3]}, 2: {6: [5, 6]}}
```