# How do you reverse a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a function -- dict_reverse(inputDict) that returns a dictionary that has inputDict's keys and values swapped. (You can assume that no values are repeated in inputDict.)

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem as I am new to dictionaries. I understand their concept and how to use them, but I am stuck as for reversing them.

```py
def dict_reverse(inputDict):
    '''dict_reverse(inputDict) -> dict
    returns dict with keys/values of inputDict swapped'''
    # add my code here

testDict = {'adam':80,'betty':60,'charles':50}
reversedDict = dict_reverse(testDict)
print(reversedDict)
# should output {80:'adam',60:'betty',50:'charles'} in some order
```

it should output `{80:'adam',60:'betty',50:'charles'}`

Comment: @YaakovBressler, That's not a dupe.

Comment: Sorry about that @Austin, meant to include this one: [Python reverse / invert a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3

```
def dict_reverse(inputDict):
    '''dict_reverse(inputDict) -> dict
    returns dict with keys/values of inputDict swapped'''
    return dict((v,k) for k,v in inputDict.items())

testDict = {'adam':80,'betty':60,'charles':50}
reversedDict = dict_reverse(testDict)
print(reversedDict)
```

Output {80: 'adam', 60: 'betty', 50: 'charles'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict-comprehension and swap the `k, v` pairs:

```
def dict_reverse(inputDict):
    return {v: k for k, v in inputDict.items()}

testDict = {'adam': 80, 'betty': 60, 'charles': 50}
reversedDict = dict_reverse(testDict)
print(reversedDict)
```

Output:

```
{80: 'adam', 60: 'betty', 50: 'charles'}
```