# How to read a text file, substitute chars using a dictionary and then save to a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is an assignment for school. I am using the following code:

```
def main():
    letters = create_letters()
    infile = open('note.txt', 'r')
    text = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    outfile = open('notetranslate.txt', 'w')
    outfile.write(text[letters])
    outfile.close()

def create_letters():
    return {'A':'`', 'a':'~', "B":'1', 'b':'!', 'C':'2', 'c':'@', 'D':'3', 'd': '#', 'E':'4', 
    'e':'$', 'F':'5', 'f':'%', 'G':'6', 'g':'^', 'H':'7', 'h':'&', 'I':'8', 'i':'*', 'J':'9', 'j':'(', 
    'K':'0', 'k':')', 'L':'-', 'l':'_', 'M':'=', 'm':'+', 'N':'[', 'n':'{', 'O':']', 'o':'}',
    'P':'|', 'p':'/', 'Q':';', 'q':':', 'R':',', 'r':'<', 'S':'.','s':'>','T':'?', 't':'"',
    'U':'`', 'u':'~', 'V':'1', 'v':'!', 'W':'2', 'w':'@', 'X':'3', 'x':'#', 'Y':'4','y':'$', 
    'Z':'5', "z":'%'}
main()
```

Upon running this code I get an error: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict.

My task is to write a program that will read the contents of the text file, then use the dictionary of codes to write an encrypted version of the files contents to a separate text file.  Each character in the second text file should contain the encrypted version of text.

Write a second program (or add a menu of options for the user to your current program) that opens an encrypted version and displays the decrypted text back on the screen for the user to read

Comment: Why would `text[a dictionary!]` work? The first thing that comes to mind is to iterate over the file's content letter by letter and do the substitution on each letter. There are other ways as well

Answer (score 1):

The objective is to substitute character by character the string with the dict in `letters`.

```
infile = open('note.txt', 'r')
text = infile.read() # read not readlines
infile.close()

subs_text = []
for letter in text:
    subs_text.append(letters[letter]) # lookup the character to be substituted with
subs_text = "".join(subs_text)

outfile = open('notetranslate.txt', 'w+') # use w+ to create file if it does not exist
outfile.write(subs_text)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Now try to think what happens if the file is very very big. You are holding up a huge list in memory and then also adding a huge string. Try to think if that can be avoided

Comment: I agree that this would be a problem in certain cases. However, it's quite an orthogonal concern to the OP's question. It seems inappropriate to increase the complexity of the answer to such an extent when the OP is clearly a novice to the language.

Comment: Making that change it gives me a TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Which string? `subs_text`?

Comment: line 8:  subs_text.append(letter[letters])

Comment: It's the other way around. `letters[letter]`

Comment: If I swap it that way now I am getting: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: subs_text is a list. You might be using the overwritten one after merging all the characters with `"".join`.

Comment: Fizzybear, thank you for the help. The problem ended up being that the subs_text line was indented in the for loop and that there was a question mark in the text file which was giving a key error. Got it figure out, thank you for the help. What would be the best way to go about now decrypting the encrypted file?

Comment: You need to invert your `letters` dict and use this new dict to perform substitution on the ciphertext. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/reverse-invert-a-dictionary-mapping