# How to reverse the assignment of values to keys in a dictionary? solve the algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

The groups_per_user function receives a dictionary, which contains group names with the list of users. Like the groups in Linux system. Users can belong to multiple groups. Fill in the blanks to return a dictionary with the users as keys and a list of their groups as values.

basically I'm trying to reverse the assignment of groups to users instead of users to groups

#### That's what I have tried so far:

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    groups = []
    # Go through group_dictionary
    for group,users in group_dictionary.items():
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for user in users:
        # Now add the group to the list of
          # groups for this user, creating the entry
          # in the dictionary if necessary
          groups.append(group)
          user_groups[user] = group

    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

How can I traverse throw the list and at the same time add the user to the group name as efficient as possible?

Please excuse my grammars, that's my fist question here. Thank you

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/485368/2947378 ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Fill in the blanks"? What blanks?

Comment: 1. You probably dont need the `groups`list at all. 2. The values in your `user_groups` dict doesnt make sense - you are setting it to a single group, when what you probably really want is a list (or even better, a set) os the groups that user is in. 3. The logic can be further simplified by using a `defaultdict` whose value-default is a `set()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue with your code is that there is only one `groups` list, when what you actually want is a list of groups for each user. Try this

```py
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for group, users in group_dictionary.items():
        for user in users:
            if user not in user_groups:
                user_groups[user] = []
            user_groups[user].append(group)
    return user_groups
```

Alternatively, we could replace those three lines with a `setdefault` call:

```py
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for group, users in group_dictionary.items():
        for user in users:
            user_groups.setdefault(user, []).append(group)
    return user_groups
```

A third option is to use a defaultdict:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = defaultdict(list)
    for group, users in group_dictionary.items():
        for user in users:
            user_groups[user].append(group)
    return user_groups
```

Comment: That works too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Never mind guys I just solved it.
all I needed is to get the group by user and concatenate it an empty list:

new code is

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    # Go through group_dictionary
    for group,users in group_dictionary.items():
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for user in users:
        # Now add the group to the the list of
          # groups for this user, creating the entry
          # in the dictionary if necessary
          user_groups[user] = user_groups.get(user,[]) + [group]

    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = defaultdict(set)
    for group, users in group_dictionary.items():
        for user in users:
            user_groups[user].add(group)
    return user_groups
```