# Plotly: How to change legend item names?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to change the names of the items in the legend. A reproducible example below.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
colorsIdx = {'setosa': '#c9cba3', 'versicolor': '#ffe1a8',
             'virginica': '#e26d5c'}
cols      = df['species'].map(colorsIdx)

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color=cols)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Because i assigned my own colors to the species i want to rename the legend so it doesn't appear as '#c9cba3', '#ffe1a8' & '#e26d5c'. instead i want to be "setosa" "versicolor" & "virginica"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general you can use:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = newnames[t.name]))
```

Where in your case `newnames` would be the `dict`:

```
{'#c9cba3': 'setosa', '#ffe1a8': 'versicolor', '#e26d5c': 'virginica'}
```

And you've already specified a dict with similar info in `colorsIdx`, so you just need to [switch `keys` and `values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/reverse-invert-a-dictionary-mapping) with:

```
newnames = {y:x for x,y in colorsIdx.items()}
```

[image]

***However***,  you should be aware that there's more going on here! In `px.scatter()`, the `color` argument has got little to do with actual colors, but rather which variable in a pandas dataframe to look for unique values to assign a color to. Have a look at what happens when you change your:

```
colorsIdx = {'setosa': '#c9cba3', 'versicolor': '#ffe1a8',
             'virginica': '#e26d5c'}
```

...to:

```
colorsIdx = {'setosa': '#magic', 'versicolor': '#color',
             'virginica': '#function'}
```

The colors are the very same in your sample plot because of what I explained initially:

[image]

To actually specify colors in your case, use `color_discrete_map=dict()` and use `color` for `species` variable. This way you can *actually* define your desired colors, and you won't have to rename your legend elements.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species',
              color_discrete_map={'setosa': 'steelblue', 
                                  'versicolor': 'firebrick',
                                  'virginica': 'green'})
fig.show()
```

Comment: I copy your complete code, but I am facing a problem in each plotly created graph and it is about legend. The legend is `species = setosa, sepecies=versiclor, sepecies = virginica `. How to get rid from these, especially in line graph. Please look at this [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49120051/125181893-f57a4e00-e226-11eb-8f0d-6faa2895264b.png) whose legend differ from yours!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that doesnt rely on creating dict of existing names because sometimes you dont care what the existing legend is and just want to change it

```
for i,trace in enumerate (fig.data):
  trace.update(name=name_list[i])
```