# efficient way to combine keys with same values in python dictionary

Tags: python

For example, I have the following dictionary

```
{'key1':value1,'key2':value2,'key3':value1,.......}}
```

I want to change it to the following form:

```
{value1:[key1,key2],value2:[key3],....}
```

I have written the following to accomplish this task. However, I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it. Is there a better way to perform this task ?

```
node_cluster = {}

for node,cluster in zip(partition.keys(),partition.values()):
    if cluster not in node_cluster.keys():
        node_cluster[cluster] = []
    node_cluster[cluster].append(node)
```

Comment: Try `for node,cluster in partition.items():`

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution. You might consider using a [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) to clean up some of the boilerplate.

Comment: I think that's about as good as you can do. This question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/485368/2860127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make the code a little bit shorter. A `defaultdict(list)` will automatically create an empty list as value when you try to access a key that doesn't exist yet :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}

out = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    out[v].append(k)
    
print(out)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b']})
```

Comment: This is the right answer but is missing `for k, v in d.items():`.

Comment: @superbrain Oops... Yes, looks like I slipped and deleted a line just before copying... Now it's back, thanks !