# Lookup values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a imported a .json list with my data, turning it into a list of dictionaries.

The keys are column headers.  For a given value of a certain key I would like to get to the value of another key in the same dictionary.

```
data = [

   {
   "Nr.": 2,
   "Table data": "S - Sulfur",
   "Ref.": 571,
   "Formula": "S",
   "Name": "Sulfur",
 },
 {
   "Nr.": 3,
   "Table data": "HF - Hydrogen Fluoride",
   "Ref.": 556,
   "Formula": "HF",
   "Name": "Hydrogen Fluoride",
 },
 {
   "Nr.": 4,
   "Table data": "N2 - Nitrogen",
   "Ref.": 5,
   "Formula": "N2",
   "Name": "Nitrogen",
 },
]
```

so for example given a user input of "Nitrogen" I would like to retrieve the value of the key "Formula" i.e. "N2.

I would convert the list of dictionaries into a dataframe and then use the lookup method.

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_json("file.json")

df = pandas.DataFrame(data,
                      columns=('Nr.', 'Table data','Ref','Formula','Name'))

df['Formula'] = df.lookup(df.index,df['Nitrogen'])
```

however matching a string with a value in this dataframe seems to be giving a KeyError every time.

Comment: `df['Nitrogen']` means select column called `Nitrogen`, if not exist returned KeyError.

Comment: What is expected output after `df['Formula'] = df.lookup(df.index,df['Nitrogen'])` ?

Comment: If you want to look up a key for a given value in a dict, you could consider inverting the dict for that purpose; or making an inverted copy of that dict. For inverting a dict, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/reverse-invert-a-dictionary-mapping .

Comment: I think you are looking for the following line of code `df[df['Name'] == 'Nitrogen']`

Comment: The actual data list is much longer.  The expectation would be, given a list of names to get the list of matching formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) if you want to match the column values against multiple elements as:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data,
                      columns=('Nr.', 'Table data','Ref','Formula','Name'))

inp_list = ['Nitrogen', 'Sulfur']
out = df[df.Name.isin(inp_list)]
print(out['Formula'])
```

Output:

```
0     S
2    N2
```

Also, note that [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) is deprecated and you should use `DataFrame.melt` and `DataFrame.loc` instead.

Comment: Thanks this works fine.  Any idea why it also includes the value of the first column '"Nr." ?

Comment: it seems it is a default behavior to print the index when a `dataframe` is dumped using print. However, you can skip the index using `out['Formula'].to_string(index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.match on the specific column in the dataframe, e.g.,

```
s= input()
df["Table data"].str.match(f".*{s}.*")
```