# How can I flatten a dictionary with a list for values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.7

I am trying to "flatten" a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {
    "USA": ["US", "United States"],
    "SGP": ["JP", "Japan", "Singapore"]
}
```

The format I would like to get it into is this:

```
new_d = {
    "United States": "USA",
    "US": "USA",
    "JP": "SGP",
    "Japan": "SGP",
    "Singapore": "SGP"
}
```

Comment: Related: [Reverse / invert a dictionary mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483666/6045800)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension with nested iteration:

```
>>> d = {
...     "USA": ["US", "United States"],
...     "SGP": ["JP", "Japan", "Singapore"]
... }
>>> {i: k for k, v in d.items() for i in v}
{'US': 'USA', 'United States': 'USA', 'JP': 'SGP', 'Japan': 'SGP', 'Singapore': 'SGP'}
```

- `k, v in d.items()` -> `k = "USA", ...`, `v = ["US", "United States"], ...`
- `i in v` -> `i = "US", ...`

hence:

- `{i: k ...}` -> `{"US": "USA", ...}`