# How to search list item by a keyword from itself in Python

Tags: python

I have a list `ListA`:

```
ListA = [ 'Key1: test1',  'Key2: test2', 'Key3: test3']
```

What I'm trying to do is I want to search a certain value to it respective key. For example: If user input `test1`, it should return me `Key1` **OR** If user input `test3`, it should return me `Key3` . I research a lot on the internet but it seem many are talking about comparing the two different list but not comparing the same list. I'm still new to programming, so I want to ask  does my idea are lousy? Is it a better way to do it ?

Comment: Your `DictA` is not a dict at all, it's a list of strings.

Comment: Keys will always be unique but values may be duplicates. what is the expectation if the user puts in a value which would map to multiple keys?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle In my case, user can only input 1 key at once. They're not allow to search multiple keys

Comment: Where does your data in such a format come from? Couldn't you get it in a more useful format?

Comment: but what if you had  `ListA = [ 'Key1: test1',  'Key2: test2', 'Key3: test2']` if the user inputs test2 what would be the expected output? since test2 maps to 2 different keys

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Cause the list will not have a duplicate value, everything is unique

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Originally the key are retrieve from a json list `{'serial1': 'key1', 'subject1': 'test1', 'serial2': 'key2', 'subject2': 'test2', 'serial3': 'key3', 'subject3': 'test3'}`

Comment: So just use the `json` module in order to get a real dict, and if you are sure that your values are unique, you can [invert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/reverse-invert-a-dictionary-mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem as originally presented:

```py
from typing import Dict, List


ListA = ['Key1: test1',  'Key2: test2', 'Key3: test3']

def get_key_from_value_list(target_list: List, target_value: str):
    for entry in target_list:
        key, list_value = entry.split(":")
        if target_value == list_value.strip():
            return key

print("List:", get_key_from_value_list(ListA, "test1"))
```

Result:

```
List: Key1
```

But given that you mentioned you're deserialising JSON, you would be better off using the actual `json` module in Python to parse it so you get an actual `dict` object, which makes this much easier than dealing with a list. Doing so would then require:

```py
from typing import Dict, List
import json

dict_a = json.loads('{"Key1": "test1","Key2": "test2","Key3": "test3"}')

def get_key_from_value_dict(target_dict: Dict, target_value: str):
    for key, value in target_dict.items():
        if target_value == value:
            return key

print("Dict: ", get_key_from_value_dict(dict_a, "test1"))
```

Result:

```
Dict:  Key1
```