# Sort list by dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting

I want to sort a list by a dictionary, as shown below:

The list:

```
L = ['Jack', 'King', '9', 'King', '10']
```

The dictionary:

```
D = {0:'Ace', 1:'King', 2:'Queen', 3:'Jack', 4:'10', 5:'9'}
```

I want to sort L based on keys of dictionary D, such that the output would be:

`[ 'King', 'King', 'Jack', '10', '9' ]`

I tried:

```
sorted(L, key = D.get)
```

but got error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 

----> 3 sorted(L, key = D.get)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Why did I get this error? Aren't the dictionary keys integers?

---

Update:

Similar question:
[Reverse / invert a dictionary mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483666/11901732)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first create another `dict` which reverses the mapping of the original `dict`, then sort based on that.

```py
revd = {v:k for k, v in D.items()}
res = sorted(L, key=revd.get)
```

Comment: Hi Unmitigated, thank you for your solution. Could you please explain what `v:k` means?

Comment: @nilsinelabore It's used in the dict comprehension here to map each value to its key, creating a reverse mapping.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a reverse mapping to map names to values instead:

```
R = dict(map(reversed, D.items()))
print(sorted(L, key=R.get))
```

Answer (score -2):

A dictionary in python has two fields, key, and value.

```
dict{key: value}
```

The sort function doesn't know what to look for when it's sorting. You can create a normal function or a lambda function that returns the value based on which it should sort the list/dictionary and pass it in the key argument of the sort function.

like this

```py
d.sort(key=lambda d:d[x]) 
# Set the value of x to 0 or 1 if you want to sort them by key or values respectively.
```

You can refer to this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/3Tcq_dBhIrQ?t=118)