# Pandas convert multiple columns datatypes at once

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, dtype

I need to change the dtypes of some columns of two different DF in my code. They are originally a Spark DF, so directly when I convert them to pandas I don't have the option to set to category dtype (that's why I am doing as a secondary step, not when the DF is created).

The DF's have most, not all, of the columns in common. I decided to create only one function to handle both cases. I created a logic where I store the columns names and the dtypes as a dictionary and then I loop through the dict items to convert the columns of the dataframe.

The dataframes are large (around 500k rows, 30-40 columns). The best way I found so far was using .apply to perform the transformation.

Would there be a faster way of doing this instead of using .apply and lambda that I could try? Here's a simple example with the function I created:

```
def dtypes_preprocess(df):

  cols_cat = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E']
  cols_float = ['F']
  cols_numerical_int32 = ['G', 'H']

  dict_dtypes = {'category' : cols_cat, 'float' : cols_float, 'int32' : cols_numerical_int32}

  for data_type, columns_dict in dict_dtypes.items():
    existing_cols = list(set(columns_dict).intersection(df.columns)) #check which columns from the list exist in the dataframe
    df[existing_cols] = df[existing_cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype(data_type, errors = 'ignore')) #perform the transformation
    
  return df
```

I was already able to improve a bit, my first attempt was like this:

```
for data_type, columns in dict_dtypes.items():
  for col in columns:
    if col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(data_type, errors = 'ignore')
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you create a dict of `name -> dtype` and pass this to `.astype` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your attempt is not bad. As [@jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19355181/jqurious) mentioned in the comment (thanks a lot for that), it could be done by passing mapping `name -> dtype` to `df.astype`.

So we just need to "invert" the `dict_dtypes` and choose only the column names present in `df`

My idea:

```py
def dtypes_preprocess(df):
  dict_dtypes = {
     'category' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'],
     'float' : ['F'],
     'int32' : ['G', 'H']
  }
  dtypes = {col: dtype for dtype in dict_dtypes for col in dict_dtypes[dtype] if col in df}
  return df.astype(dtypes, errors='ignore')
```

The dictionary comprehension looks a bit harder to read, though -- any suggestions are welcome here.

(Idea for "inverting" the `dict_dtypes` taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483666/13224210).)

Comment: Thank you @Matej. The runtime was reduced with your suggestion